# Solve the equation $x^4+y^4=d*z^2$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Solve the equation:$$x^4+y^4=d*z^2,$$
where $x,y,z$ are positive integers,and $d>1$ is a given square-free integer.

I know if $p$ is an odd prime and $p|d,$ then $t^4\equiv -1 \pmod p$ is solvable,so $p\equiv 1 \pmod 8$,but this is not sufficient.

PS:I just want to know how to determine whether $x^4+y^4=d*z^2$ has any positive integer solutions,not ask how to get all the solutions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, you got the solution for $x^4+y^4=41z^2$?

Comment: @Inceptio,Not yet,I just want a more general solution,so I removed the equation $x^4+y^4=41z^2$ from the post.But if you have any ideas,you can show it with this special equation.

Comment: Using the methode that I explain [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/367492/5189) you can find integral solutions of $x^2 + y^2 = 41z^2$, by reducing them to rational solutions of $x^2 + y^2 = 41$ and noting that $5^2 + 4^2 = 41$. Then I would hope that there is an easy way to find out if these solutions can be squares. (For instance, hope that they are $2$ or $3$ mod $4$.)

Comment: @Myself,thank you,but it's difficult to find a square solution in the solutions of $x^2+y^2=d*z^2$.