# Where is this formula for generating pythagorean triples coming from?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm reading Stillwell's *Mathematics and Its History*. In the chapter about pythagorean triples, he says that we now know that the general formula for generating pythagorean triples is:

$$a = r\cdot(m^2 - n^2)   ,\ \, b = r\cdot(2mn) ,\ \, c = r\cdot(m^2 + n^2)\tag{1}$$

And that there is a special case which gives all solutions $a,b,c$ without common divisor:

$$a = m^2 - n^2 ,\ \, b = 2mn ,\ \, c = m^2 + n^2\tag{2}$$

I'm just no so sure where are these formulas coming from. I've made the following trial: By looking $(2)$, I've written the formula for the pythagorean theorem and I've switched only the $c$:

$$a^2+b^2=\color{red}{(m^2 + n^2)^2}$$

And expanded it:

$$a^2+b^2=\color{red}{m^4+2n^2m^2+n^4}\tag{3}$$

Then my guess is that I should find arbitrary $a$, $b$ (and perhaps some integers?) written in terms of $n$ and $m$ such that $(3)$ is true. So I guess I need to split the polynomial in (perhaps) some arbitrary way such as:

$$a^2+b^2=\color{red}{m^4+2n^2m^2}\color{green}{+n^4}$$
$$a^2+b^2=\color{red}{m^4+n^2m^2}\color{green}{+n^2m^2+n^4}$$

And then find $a,b$ such that:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  {a^2}&=&{m^4+2n^2m^2} \\ 
  {b^2}&=&{n^4} 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Or:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  {a^2}&=&{m^4+n^2m^2} \\ 
  {b^2}&=&{n^2m^2+n^4} 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Or any arbitrary combination such that $(3)$ holds. I'm still a little stuck, am I on the right path? I've looked wikipedia article on pythagorean triples and there's no much insight into this matter.

Comment: From where ? From [Euclid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple). :-)

Comment: @Lucian Yes. The worst part is that it's all in there. I've seen "proof" and somehow I thought that it wouldn't answer my question. Where's the *"I feel ashamed for asking such a dumb question and want to delete it to avoid future embarassment"* button?

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/423196).

Comment: @Pristine, don't worry about it.  We all sometimes feel like we're asking dumb questions.  But really, the only dumb questions are the ones you **don't** ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read a few pages further you will find  that Exercises 1.31. and 1.3.2 give a derivation of the Pythagorean triple formula using a rational parametrization of the circle (see also  the "geometry" section of the [Wikipedia article).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Geometry_of_Euclid%27s_formula)

More generally, if a conic curve with rational coefficients has one rational point $\rm\:P\:$ then it has infinitely many, since any rational line through $\rm\:P\:$ will intersect the curve in another point, necessarily rational, since if one root of a rational quadratic is rational then so is the other. Therefore, by *sweeping lines* of varying rational slopes through $\rm\:P\:$ we obtain infinitely many rational points on the conic.  Projecting these points onto a line leads to a *rational parametrization* of the conic. For a very nice exposition see Chapter $1$ of Silverman and Tate: *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves*. There are also many online expositions, e.g. search on "rational parametrization Pythagorean triple".

There are also many other ways to derive the formula. A particularly beautiful one-line way employs Hilbert's Theorem $90$ - see the award winning expository *Monthly* paper by Olga Taussky [Sums of Squares.](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/OlgaTaussky.pdf)

Comment: I got sad for asking such a stupid question - after you said the answer is in wikipedia, I noticed it really was. But when you answered the question and provided references, I got really happy! I'm a books colector, then answers with references are a supreme delight, specially coming from a very qualified member of the mathematical community like you. Thanks! If you have some blog or website where you recommend books and articles, please let me know.

Comment: Don't worry, we all pondered this question at one point on our learning curve. The geometrical approach is very pretty so I recommend that you read about it. Another beautiful geometrical viewpoint is the reflective generation of the [ternary tree of primitive Pythagorean triples](http://mathoverflow.net/a/33726/6716) due to Aubry.

Answer (score 3):

There is a fair bit of work to do to prove this theorem but you could look [here](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~angell/articles/algnumtheory.pdf), starting on page 2.  The article is aimed at a secondary school level audience, so hopefully it should be fairly accessible.

Note that the main difficulty is not proving that the formulae give some possible $a,b,c$ but proving that they give **all** possible $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from a rather sneaky relation that $2m^2n^2=4m^2n^2-2m^2n^2$. If we have $c=m^2+n^2$, then $$c^2=(m^2+n^2)^2=m^4+2m^2n^2+n^4=\\m^4-2m^2n^2+n^4+4m^2n^2=(n^2-m^2)^2+(2mn)^2=a^2+b^2$$ where $a=(m^2+n^2),b=2mn$.

Comment: That doesn't actually prove anything since you're assuming a certain form for $c$.