Complex Numbers as Generalization of "Signdedness"?
I only have a minor in math, so please don't judge to harshly.
I have a question about complex numbers. This intuition (I assume) doesn't capture their essence in whole, but I presume is fundamental.
So, complex numbers basically generalize the notion of sign (+/-), right? In the reals only, we can reinterpret - (negative sign) as "180 degrees", and + as "0 degrees", and then see that multiplying two numbers involves summing these angles to arrive at the sign for the product:

sign of positive * positive => 0 degrees + 0 degrees => positive
sign of positive * negative => 0 degrees + 180 degrees => negative
[third case symmetric to second]
sign of negative * negative => 180 degrees + 180 degrees => 360 degrees => 0 degrees => positive

Then, sign of i is 90 degrees, sign of -i = -1 * i = 180 degrees + 90 degrees = 270 degrees, and finally sign of -i * i = 270 + 90 = 360 = 0 (positive)
So this (adding angles and multiplying magnitudes) matches the definition for multiplication of complex numbers, and we might after the extension of reals to the complex plain, say we've been doing this all along (under interpretation of - as 180 degrees).
So we have infinite "signs" (arg(z)) now which is great.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

I’m voting to close this question because there's no question in it.

Please use MathJax to make your question readable.

I guess the question is, "is this a good interpretation / motivation for complex multiplication?" to which I say yes, this is a good starting point.

I made an argument for a geometric definition of the complex numbers as abstractions of rotations which seems to be in the same spirit as your idea regarding signs. You can find it here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731876/why-do-complex-numbers-lend-themselves-to-rotation/4731892#4731892

No, @Henriksupportsthecommunity, there is a question in it. There's a feature called CTRL + F that allows you to search for text on a page -- do that and enter a question mark, or try reading it again.
The problem with all the stack exchange website is that they're filled with unreceptive, pedantic "rule enforcers" and experts who seem to relish shooting down the lowly commoners who dare enter their territory. Always inaccessible to newcomers.

Oh yeah, there is a question mark in there, and thereby a question. But the question mark is in the middle of a paragraph, not a good place to place the question. You should think about that when writing question and possibly when editing this to have it reopened. And the fact that there's a comment formulating a question based on your text, is also an indication that it's too hard to find. And a note about terminology: The feature is not called ctrl+f, it's called "search", ctrl+f is just a keybinding to access that feature.
