# Proof of Euclid Lemma explanation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

Proof:

> Lemma (Euclid). Let $p$ be a prime, and let $a, b$ be integers. If $p | ab$ then $p | a$ or $p | b$. Assume $p$ is the smallest prime for
>   which this assertion fails, and let $a$ and $b$ be such that $p | ab$
>   and $p ∤ a$ and $p ∤ b$. By replacing $a$ and $b$ with their
>   remainders when dividing by $p$, we may assume that $1 ≤ a < p$ and $1≤ b < p$. Then $kp = ab$; clearly, $1 ≤ k < p$. We have $k ≠ 1$ since
>   $p$ is a prime. Let $q$ be a prime divisor of $k$. Then $q | ab$, and
>   so, **by the minimality assumption on $p$**, we have $q | a$ or $q | b$. Then dividing $q$ into $k$ and into one of $a$ or $b$, we obtain
>   an equation $k ′p = a ′ b ′$ , where $1 ≤ k ′ < k$, $1 ≤ a ′ < p$, and
>   $1 ≤ b ′ < p$. Repeating this step as long as necessary, we arrive at
>   an equation $k ′′p = a ′′b ′′$ with $k ′′ = 1$, $1 ≤ a ′′ < p$, and $1≤ b ′′ < p$. This equation contradicts the primality of $p$,
>   completing the proof.

I have bolded the part that I do not understand. The proof starts with the assumption that $p$ is the smallest prime number for which the lemma does not hold. My question is does that mean then that $q > p$ in this specific proof? Since the prime $q$ *can* divide $a$ or $b$.

Comment: No, $q<p$, hence the "induction" hypothesis applies to $q$.  Specifically, $k<p$ and $q$ is a divisor of $k$, hence $q≤k<p$.

Comment: Is $p>|ab$ a typo.?

Comment: "My question is does that mean then that q>p in this specific proof? Since the prime q can divide a or b."  No, the exact opposite.  As $q \le k < p$ we have $q < p$ and therefore as $p$ was the smallest prime that divide neither we can conclude that $p$ most divide at least one of them.

Comment: By the minimality assumption Euclid's Lemma holds for all primes $\, q < p,\ $ so $\, q\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\, q\mid a\,$ or $\,q\mid b\ \ $

Comment: The reason this proof is so convoluted is due to the lack of symmetry. If you are interested I can post a simpler more symmetric proof along these lines.

Comment: The real problem here is that the author's proof contains a hidden induction (or hidden application of the well-ordering principle). Those are essential ingredients, and by trying to hide them, the author's made a hash of things. I know this doesn't answer the question, but I'd suggest switching to a different text.

Comment: I did not work this proof. I copied it from a website.

Comment: @BillDubuque I am confused. The proof starts with statement that $p$ is the least prime for which it fails. How can then $q < p$ be a prime for which it does not fail? Or does it mean for all the primes that fail $p$ is the smallest one and then there can be other primes less than $p$ for which it does not fail?

Comment: I found the link http://www.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/~mate/heartofmath/euclids_lemma.pdf

Brooklyn CUNY / Attila Máté

Comment: @MichaelMunta If if failed also for a prime $\,q < p\,$ then $\,p\,$ would not be the least prime for which it fails. Thus it is true for all primes $\, q < p.\ $  The idea is simply that if it fails then the set of naturals where it fails is nonempty so it has a least element ([minimal criminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_counterexample)) by the [Least Number Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle)

Comment: @Bill Ah, of course I thought about this the wrong way. Would you be willing to post your version of this proof as you said?

Answer (score 2):

Update: In this simpler rework of our initial argument, the [method of infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent) isn't used. But getting the 'step-down' counterexample is still the main idea.

---

The OP's tightly packed proof (copied from a website) has many moving parts, so here we want to organize it so that the main ideas shine through.

If Euclid's lemma isn't true, it will fail for a least $p$ (the 'minimal criminal'), and, for that $p$, a choice of integers $a_0$ and $b_0$ with the smallest product $a_0 b_0$, giving us our 'conditioned counterexample',

$\quad p \mid a_0 b_0 \text{ and } p \nmid a_0 \text{ and } p \nmid b_0$

It must be true that $a_0 \lt p$ (if not replacing $a_0$ with $a_0 - p$ gives a smaller product $(a_0 - p) b_0$ and a 'better' counterexample), and for the same reason, $b_0 \lt p$.

Using simple logic to sharpen the inequalities, the counterexample satisfies

There exists $p, a_0, b_0 \in \Bbb N$ with $p$ a prime number such that
$\tag 1 (\forall \text{ prime } z) \; \big[\text{IF } z \lt p \text{ THEN } (\forall x,y \in \Bbb N)\;z \mid xy \, \text{ implies }\, z \mid x \text{ or } z \mid y\;\big]$
$\quad \text{ AND } \quad \; \,[\;p \mid a_0 b_0  \text { and } 1 \lt a_0 \lt p \text{ and }  1 \lt b_0 \lt p\;] $

Using the second conjunct of $\text{(1)}$ we can write write $kp = a_0 b_0$ for some $k \ge 2$. Let $q$ be any prime factor of $k$. Since $q \lt p$, by the first conjunct of $\text{(1)}$ it must divide into either $a_0$ or $b_0$, allowing us, after factoring it out of one of the multiplicands, to write as true

$$\tag 2 p \mid a_1 b_1  \text { and } 1 \le a_1 \lt p \text{ and }  1 \le b_1  \lt p $$

where $a_1 \lt a_0 \text{ or } b_1 \lt b_0$ (a 'step down' on the natural numbers $a_0$ and $b_0$) giving $a_1 b_1 \lt a_0 b_0$. Since $\text{(2)}$ also provides a counterexample, the starting counterexample $\text{(1)}$ must be rejected.

By employing reductio ad absurdum we have demonstrated Euclid's lemma.

---

From Cut-The-Knot, [What Is Infinite Descent?](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/WhatIs/WhatIsInfiniteDescent.shtml):

> Let $P$ be a property that integers may or may not possess. If an assumption that a positive integer $n_0$ has property $P$ leads to the existence of a smaller positive integer $n_1 \lt n_0$ that also satisfies $P$, then no positive integer has that property.

Comment: I like that phrase "moving parts". The phrase "infinite decent" is from Fermat.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet The proof Euclid's_Element:BookVII.Prop31 is interesting as it doesn't require a 'minimal criminal', it shows that any old number has a prime factor since infinite descent must be excluded. https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVII/propVII31.html

Comment: We can avoid a chain $a_0,...,a_n$ if, after assuming $p_0$ is the least prime $p$ for which the Lemma fails, we assume  $m_0$ is the least $ m$ such that there exist $ab$ with $p_0|ab=m$ and $(p_0\not |a \land p_0\not |b).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet See my update - I think it now better represents the infinite descent logic. I mean, who really wants an algorithm to reach a contradiction!

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Infinite descent on at least one natural number means that 'logic crystals are shattering' and it doesn't matter where.

Comment: Why would allowing $a_1 = 1$ or $b_1 = 1$ make statement $(2)$ false?