# Given integer $b \gt 1$ use infinite descent to prove that every integer $m \gt 0$ has one and only one Base-$b$ representation.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, infinite-descent

My motivation for looking into this was sparked by the 'big-list' question

[What are the principal (different) mechanisms of infinite descent proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1715174/432081)

> Is the following proof valid?

---

If an integer $m \gt 0$ is expressed in [capital sigma notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Capital-sigma_notation),

$$\tag 1 m = \sum_{k=0}^n m_k\, b^k \quad \text{ with } \forall k,\, 0 \le m_k \lt b \text{ and } m_n \ne 0$$

then we say that $m$ has a Base-$b$ representation of degree $n$.

Two Base-$b$ representations of $m$ are said to be identical if they have the same degree and if all the corresponding $m$ [coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient) are equal.

**Existence**

Suppose $a \gt 0$ doesn't have a representation. Using Euclidean division (existence part),

$$\tag 2 a = bq + r \text{ with } 0 \le r \lt b$$

Clearly $a$ must be greater than or equal to $b$, and so $q \gt 0$.

If there was a representation for $q$,

$$\quad q = \sum_{k=0}^n q_k\, b^k$$

then

$$\quad a = r + \sum_{k=0}^n q_k\, b^{k+1}$$

would give a representation of $a$. So $q$ can't have a representation.

Finally, by $\text{(2)}$ we must have $q \lt a$ and by the [method of infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent) we arrive at a contradiction.

So every $a \gt 0$ has a Base-$b$ representation.

**Uniqueness**

Firstly observe that

$$\tag 3 a = \sum_{k=0}^n x_k\, b^k = x_0 + b \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x_{k+1}\, b^k$$

Let $a \gt 0$ have two different representations,

$\quad a = \sum_{k=0}^n x_k\, b^k = x_0 + b \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x_{k+1}\, b^k =$
$\quad\quad\quad \sum_{k=0}^{n'} y_k\, b^k = y_0 + b \sum_{k=0}^{n'-1} y_{k+1}\, b^k$

Clearly $a$ must be greater than or equal to $b$.

Using the above and Euclidean division (uniqueness part with divisor equal to $b$), the integer $c \gt 0$,

$\tag 4 c = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x_{k+1}\, b^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n'-1} y_{k+1}\, b^k$

has two different representations.

Clearly we must have $c \lt a$ and by the [method of infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent) we arrive at a contradiction.

So every $a \gt 0$ has a unique Base-$b$ representation.