# Produce all solutions for $2a^2 + b^2 = c^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to generate a stream of tuples $(a, b, c)$ that satisfy the equation 
$2a^2 + b^2 = c^2$

The first $10$ results are:

$2,   1,  3$

$4,   2,  6$

$6,   3,  9$

$4,   7,  9$

$6,   7,  11$

$8,   4,  12$

$10,  5,  15$

$12, 1,  17$

$12, 6, 18$

$8, 14, 18$

There is a solution for $x_2+2y_2=z_2$ which is exactly the same but I cannot understand how I can produce all these numbers as a function. For instance, it says $x_3=(a_2+2b_2)t=3$ which is the solution of $c$, in my case, but it includes $x_3$ because $t = \dfrac{1}{2}(x_1+x_3)$. In addition, he gives the values $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\} = \{1,2,3\}$ but I'm not sure which are the next values. Any help please. Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: What do you mean by the "first" ten?  How are you indexing them?

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367443/find-all-solutions-x2-2y2-z2

Comment: It is ordered by increasing values of c. If two tuples result in the same value of c, then is sorted by increasing orders of b.