# Diophantine equation $x^2+101^2y^2=2z^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I tried find solutions in integers to the equation
$$x^2+101^2y^2=2z^2$$
and I believe there doesn't exist one, but I keep missing how to prove it. I tried Looking square residue and  similar, but haven't managed to find the proof. Any tip will help.

Comment: There is a solution. You can use this formula.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513733/solving-a-diophantine-equation-of-the-form-x2-ay2-byz-cz2-with-the-co/1514030#1514030

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that $101$ is a prime.

There are two cases:

$1)$ If $101\nmid z$, then $x^2\equiv 2z^2\pmod{101}$, $(x\cdot z^{-1})^2\equiv 2\pmod{101}$ (modulo multiplicative inverse).

But $101$ is a prime of the form $8k+5$, [so this congruence/equivalence has no solutions by Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.C2.B12_and_the_second_supplement).

$2)$ If $101\mid z$, then $101\mid x^2$, by Euclid's lemma $101\mid x$.

Let $x=101a$, $z=101b$, $a,b\in\mathbb Z$.

$a^2+y^2=2b^2$. This equation has infinitely many different integer solutions. [This equation is in this Math.SE question with answers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250912/diophantine-equations-solving-a2-b2-2c2)