# $x^2+y^2=2z^2$, positive integer solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Determine all positive integer solutions of the equation $x^2+y^2=2z^2$.

First I assume $x \geq y$, and I have $x^2-z^2=z^2-y^2$. Then I have $(x-z)(x+z)=(z-y)(z+y)$, but from here, I don't know how it can help me to describe solutions (I know that there are infinitely many).

Comment: Some other posts about the same diophantine equation: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250912/diophantine-equations-solving-a2-b2-2c2
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282600/parametric-characterization-for-x2-y2-2z2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just a start:

Note that $$\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^2=\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}=z^2.$$

And $\frac{x-y}{2}$ and $\frac{x+y}{2}$ are integers (why?)

So you need to find solutions to $u^2+v^2=z^2$.

Comment: Thanks, I get it. Is there a general way to solve this type of problem, like $x^2+y^2=kz^2$

Comment: The general way is to solve $k=u^2+v^2$. If you can't solve it, then there is no solution. If you can, then you can convert the question to a question about $x_1^2+y_1^2=z_1^2$. This is related to Gaussian integers, and the fact that you have unique factorization in the Gaussian integers. In the case of $k=2$, $1^2+1^2=2$.

Answer (score 7):

In General formula generic for Pythagorean triples looks a little different.

$$x^2+y^2=az^2$$

If the number can be represented as a sum of squares.  $a=t^2+k^2$

The solution has the form:

$$x=-tp^2+2kps+ts^2$$

$$y=kp^2+2tps-ks^2$$

$$z=p^2+s^2$$

Answer (score 3):

From Brahmagupta-Fibonacci Identity: 
$${\left( {p}_{2}\,{s}_{2}+{p}_{1}\,{s}_{1}\right) }^{2}+{\left( {p}_{1}\,{s}_{2}-{s}_{1}\,{p}_{2}\right) }^{2}=\left( {p}_{2}^{2}+{p}_{1}^{2}\right) \,\left( {s}_{2}^{2}+{s}_{1}^{2}\right)$$
get:
$${\left( {p}_{2}\,{s}_{2}\,{t}_{2}+{p}_{1}\,{s}_{1}\,{t}_{2}+{p}_{1}\,{t}_{1}\,{s}_{2}-{s}_{1}\,{t}_{1}\,{p}_{2}\right) }^{2}+{\left( {p}_{1}\,{s}_{2}\,{t}_{2}-{s}_{1}\,{p}_{2}\,{t}_{2}-{t}_{1}\,{p}_{2}\,{s}_{2}-{p}_{1}\,{s}_{1}\,{t}_{1}\right) }^{2}=\left( {p}_{2}^{2}+{p}_{1}^{2}\right) \,\left( {s}_{2}^{2}+{s}_{1}^{2}\right) \,\left( {t}_{2}^{2}+{t}_{1}^{2}\right)$$
and get solution:
$${\left( {p}_{2}\,{t}_{2}^{2}+2\,{p}_{1}\,{t}_{1}\,{t}_{2}-{t}_{1}^{2}\,{p}_{2}\right) }^{2}+{\left( {p}_{1}\,{t}_{2}^{2}-2\,{t}_{1}\,{p}_{2}\,{t}_{2}-{p}_{1}\,{t}_{1}^{2}\right) }^{2}=\left( {p}_{2}^{2}+{p}_{1}^{2}\right) \,{\left( {t}_{2}^{2}+{t}_{1}^{2}\right) }^{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

Though others have posted simple solutions to the problem but if you want to proceed the way you did then here it is:

First let $\dfrac xz = a$ and $\dfrac yz = b$. This reduces problem to two variables (which are rational numbers).
Now we have $(b+1)(b-1)=(1+a)(1-a)$
which means $${b+1\over1+a} ={ 1-a\over b-1}$$
Let this fraction be $\dfrac mn$ in reduced form. From this we get 2 linear equations in 2 variables (in terms of a and b). 
Solving those will give
$$a = \frac{(n² + 2mn - m²)}{(m² + n²)}$$
$$b = {(m² + 2mn - n²)\over(m² + n²)}$$
 Substituting values of a and b back gives the solution to original problem:
$$x = n² + 2mn - m²$$ $$y = m² + 2mn - n²$$  $$z = m² + n²$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).