# How do I prove Diophantine equation has no solutions

Tags: diophantine-equations

In order to solve some bigger problem I need to prove that equation

$$z^2+y^2=nx^2$$ where $ n=6 \; mod\;8$ and $x,y,z$ are all integers, doesn't have any non-zero solutions

I was given a hint how to do it when $n=6$. Say we have

$$z^2+y^2=6x^2$$
Then we can consider that $gcd(x,y,z)=1$. Then $z^2+y^2$ is divisible by 3. It can only be if both $z^2$ and $y^2$ are divisible by 3, hence $z$ and $y$ are divisible by 3. Hence $6x^2$ has to be divisible by 9, it can only be if $x$ is divisible by 3 and we have a contradiction because $gcd(x,y,z)=3.$

I can do that trick when $n=14$ and I guess with other $n$. But I can't get the general principle. If you have any ideas. please share.

Comment: $n$  is divisible by some prime $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4$  to an odd power,  that is how you get $\frac{n}{2} \equiv 3 \pmod 4.$  However, $-1$ is not a quadratic residue $\pmod q,$  so this $q$ can only divide $x^2 + y^2$ to an even power. In brief, $x^2 + y^2 \neq n z^2 $  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/208158/isotropic-ternary-forms

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1767109/x2y2-2z2-positive-integer-solutions/1767719#1767719

Comment: If n is a square and both n and z are of the form $\space(4k+1)\space$ there "may" be as many solutions as there are distinct prime factors of the nz pr9duct. If n is not a square, there are no solutions because the nz product must be a square.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

> The only values of $z^2$, $y^2$ and $x^2$ could be, mod $8$: $0,1,4$. The only values of $nx^2$ is $0$ and $6$.

More Hint:

> $6$ cannot be achieved by adding, so the only possible case is where $x^2,y^2,z^2$ is all $0$ mod $8$, or $x^2,y^2$ are both $4$ mod $8$. In other words, $x^2,y^2,z^2$ are all multiples of $4$.

Comment: $z^{2},y^{2}$ can both be congruent to $4 \mod 8$. So that $0=4+4=z^{2}+y^{2}=6x^{2} \mod 8$ Which we can't have since then $2|z,y$. But it is not necessary that all the squares are $0 \mod 8$.