# Solving a diophantine equation x²+y²=2z²

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

solve the equation x²+y²=2z² in positive integers,
Found this question in a book named Challenge and thrill of pre college mathematics.

Its kind of obvious to prove when x=y=z but when z=√(x²+y²)/√2, i am stuck on this step and would appreciate any hint or solutions
`

Comment: I suggest: look at some of the ways to enumerate Pythagorean triples and try to adapt those methods.

Comment: do you know the parametrization for (primitive) Pythagorean triples ?  If $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$   then $(a-b)^2 + (a+b)^2 = 2 c^2$  Oh,  and primitive solutions to your problem have $x,y,z$ all odd

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Diophantine Equations problem 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781141/diophantine-equations-problem-2) (with several other duplicates linked to it, as indicated in the "Linked" section on the right side) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D2z%5E2%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegers&p=1). There's also the closely related (which uses what @WillJagy indicated in the comment above) [Parametric characterization for $x^2 + y^2 = 2z^2$](/q/1282600).

Comment: Yep i got that now , thanks everyone for suggesting things and providing a direct solution :)

Comment: $(\frac{m^2-2m-1}{m^2+1},\frac{-m^2-2m+1}{m^2+1})$...