# When $x^2+6xy+y^2$ a square number?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all natural numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2+6xy+y^2$ is a square number.

For example, $(x,y)=(2,3)$ or $(x,y)=(3,10)$.

Obviously, we can consider $gcd(x,y)=1$.

Comment: Let $s=x+y$ and $p=xy$. Then $s^2+4p=n^2$. But this is the $\Delta$ of $t^2-st-p=0$. When $\Delta=n^2$, the quadratic equation has two rational roots. At the same time, *x* and *y* are the $($integer$)$ roots of $u^2-su+p=0$.

Comment: The solution there.   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816681/find-all-integers-satisfying-m2-n-12n-1n-2n-22/816685#816685

Answer (score 6):

Stereographic projection from $(-1,0),$ I get
$$  x = m^2 - n^2, \; \; y = 2 mn + 6 n^2,  $$
with $$  \gcd(m,n) = 1, $$ 
and either $m > n > 0$ or $n < 0$ and $|n| < m < 3 |n|. $
Also $m,n$ not both odd.

Put the inequalities together, we get 
$$  m > n >  0 \; \; \mbox{OR} \; \; \frac{-m}{3} >n > -m. $$
In the latter case we are originally in the third quadrant as the rational point on the hyperbola $x^2 + 6xy+y^2 = 1$ is
$$  x= \frac{m^2 - n^2}{m^2 + 6 mn+n^2}, \; \;  y= \frac{2mn+6n^2}{m^2 + 6 mn+n^2},  $$ 
while $-m/3 > n > -m$ implies $m^2 + 6 mn + n^2 < 0.$

Improvement: If $m,n$ both odd, take
$$  x = \frac{m^2 - n^2}{4}, \; \; y = \frac{2 mn + 6 n^2}{4},  $$
final requirement here is that $m \neq n \pmod 4.$ Put another way: when both are odd, we require that $m+n$ be divisible by $4.$

The nonsense with the possible negative signs comes from the fact that we are not projecting onto an ellipse, we are projecting onto a hyperbola. So, the denominator may come up negative and solutions disappear. Need to allow $n$ negative. Let me know if I have missed any solutions; fairly easy to just splat a formula on the page, harder to figure out whether one has all solutions.

Note that, given some pair $(x,y)$ such that $x^2 + 6 xy+ y^2 = w^2$ for some $w,$ we get new pairs ( same $w$) with
$$ (-y,x+6y),  $$
$$ (-x-6y,6x+35y),  $$
$$ (-6x-35y,35x+204y),  $$
$$ (-35x-204y,204x+1189y)  $$
and so on, which pushes along the relevant hyperbola in the second or fourth quadrant.
As you will see, there is some repetition below. First ordered by $m,n$ then a short thing ordered by just $x,y.$

EDIT: this worked out very well. I just restricted to those solutions with $x>y$ and put them in order, well, backwards...Being in order, I was able to compare with a list of all solutions with $x \leq 306,$ we have a winner.

```
 x      y                m       n
306     19               35      1
300     13               37    -13
297     80               19     -8
290    171               39    -19
286    279               35      9
285     92               17      2
275     42               18     -7
273    232               17      4
270    119               37    -17
261    220               19    -10
260    189               33      7
255     38               16      1
253     12               17     -6
247    150               16      3
240     17               31      1
234    115               31      5
230     39               33    -13
225    112               17     -8
221     84               15      2
216    209               35    -19
210     11               31    -11
208     57               29      3
207     70               16     -7
200    153               33    -17
198    175               29      7
195     34               14      1
187    138               14      3
184    105               31    -15
182     15               27      1
176    105               27      5
171     10               14     -5
168     65               29    -13
165     76               13      2
161    144               15     -8
154     51               25      3
152     33               27    -11
143     30               12      1
136      9               25     -9
133     60               13     -6
132     13               23      1
126     95               23      5
119     30               12     -5
117     68               11      2
114     91               25    -13
105      8               11     -4
102     55               23    -11
 99     26               10      1
 90     11               19      1
 85     84               11     -6
 78      7               19     -7
 77     60                9      2
 70     39               17      3
 65     24                9     -4
 63     22                8      1
 56      9               15      1
 55      6                8     -3
 52     45               17     -9
 44     21               15     -7
 40     33               13      3
 36      5               13     -5
 35     18                6      1
 30      7               11      1
 21      4                5     -2
 15     14                4      1
 12      5                7      1
 10      3                7     -3
  3      2                2     -1

      x      y                m      n
      3      2                2     -1
      3     10                2      1
      5     12                3     -2
      2      3                3      1
      5     36                3      2
      7     30                4     -3
     15     14                4      1
      7     78                4      3
      9     56                5     -4
     21      4                5     -2
     21     44                5      2
      4     21                5      3
      9    136                5      4
     11     90                6     -5
     35     18                6      1
     11    210                6      5
     13    132                7     -6
     33     40                7     -4
     10      3                7     -3
     12      5                7      1
     45     52                7      2
     33    152                7      4
      6     55                7      5
     13    300                7      6
     15    182                8     -7
     39     70                8     -5
     55      6                8     -3
     63     22                8      1
     55    102                8      3
     39    230                8      5
     15    406                8      7
     17    240                9     -8
     14     15                9     -5
     65     24                9     -4
     77     60                9      2
     65    168                9      4
      8    105                9      7
     17    528                9      8
     19    306               10     -9
     51    154               10     -7
     99     26               10      1
     91    114               10      3
     51    434               10      7
     19    666               10      9
      x      y                m      n

         x         y
         1         0
         3         2
        10         3
        12         5
        15        14
        21         4
        30         7
        35        18
        36         5
        40        33
        44        21
        52        45
        55         6
        56         9
        63        22
        65        24
        70        39
        77        60
        78         7
        85        84
        90        11
        99        26
         x         y
jagy@phobeusjunior:
```

I was curious about repetition, still with positive $x,y,$ to $x^2 + 6 xy+ y^2 = z^2.$ Plenty, and predictable, squarefree products of primes $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 8.$

```
     x      y                m      n               z
     65     24                9     -4             -119    7 . 17 
     90     11               19      1              119  

     99     26               10      1              161    7 . 23
    136      9               25     -9             -161

    143     30               12      1              217   7 . 31
    102     55               23    -11             -217

    351     14               20     -7             -391   17 . 23
    176    105               27      5              391

   2628     37              109    -37            -2737   7 . 17 . 23
   1927    318               44      3             2737
   1333    660               37      6             2737
   1025    912               33      8             2737

  81807   1030              304   -103           -84847   7 . 17 . 23 . 31
  62625   8528              271   -104           -84847
  59998   9735              491     33            84847
  55040  12177              471     41            84847
  49773  15052              247   -106           -84847
  45140  17877              429     59            84847
  39195  22018              226   -109           -84847
  35032  25353              383     81            84847
     x      y                m      n               z
```

Comment: It might be worth emphasizing that this is intersecting the pencil of lines through $(-1,0)$ (i.e., $y=ax+a$) with the ellipse $x^2+6xy+y^2=1$, since rational points $\langle\frac sw,\frac tw\rangle$ on the latter correspond to natural numbers $s$, $t$, $w$ such that $s^2+6st+t^2=w^2$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, yes, but it is a hyperbola. I am still checking whether these points suffice, there is an unpleasant bit of trickery as the number to be squared has no fixed sign, different from Pythagorean triples for example.

Answer (score 0):

For non-trivial cases, $xy\ne0$

Let $x^2+6xy+y^2=(x+ky)^2$ where $k$ is any integer

$\iff y(6x+y)=y(2kx+k^2y)\implies6x+y=2kx+k^2y\iff x(6-2k)=y(k^2-1)$

So, $\dfrac x{k^2-1}=\dfrac y{6-2k}=m$(say an integer)

As $x,y>0$ if $m<0,$ we need $6-2k<0\iff k>3\ \ \ \ (1)$ and $k^2-1<0\iff -1<k<1\ \  \ \ (2)$

There can be no $k$ satisfying both $(1),(2)$

Similarly if $m>0,$ we need $6-2k>0\iff k<3$ and $k^2-1>0\iff k>1$ or $k<-1$

$k<3,k<-1\implies k<-1$

or $k<3,k>1\implies1<k<3\implies k=2$

So, there are infinitely natural values of $x,y$

Comment: Why does $k$ need to be an integer?