# Parametrization for a curve

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Can we parametriza $x$ and $y$ in rational field $Q$ so that
$$-8xy+8x^2-4y^2$$
be square?

Comment: It is necessary to solve such an equation? $8x^2-8xy-4y^2=z^2$

Comment: If so, you have to use this formula.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738446/solutions-to-ax2-by2-cz2/738527#738527  For ease of calculation will reduce by 4. Then we will use the equivalent of a quadratic form by replacing $x$ on $x+y$

Comment: Oh sign't noticed. In integers decisions no.

Comment: If you can find one rational point on the curve, then you can take the line through that point with slope $t$, and the other interswection of line and curve will be a rational point, parametrized by $t$.

Comment: Any questions about the answer I have posted?

Comment: Are you still there?

Answer (score 1):

The requested parametrization cannot exist, since the equation has no rational solutions.

There are nonzero rational $x,y$ such that $-8xy+8x^2=4y^2$ is a (rational) square if and only if there are nonzero integers $x,y,z$ such that $$2x^2-2xy-y^2=z^2$$ from which we get $$4x^2-4xy-2y^2=2z^2=(2x-y)^2-3y^2$$ and $$(2x-y)^2\equiv2z^2\pmod3$$ but 2 is not a square mod 3, so $$z=3r,\quad 2x-y=3s,\quad 6r^2=3s^2-y^2$$ for some integers $r,s$. Then $y$ is a multiple of 3, so $x$ is a multiple of 3, so there is no nonzero solution (because, given any solution, this shows you can divide each variable by 3 to get another solution).