# Does the special Pell equation $X^2-dY^2=Z^2$ have a simple general parameterization?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

In Carmichael's *Diophantine Analysis* ($\S8$), he notes that the equation
$$X^2-dY^2=Z^2  \qquad(\dagger)$$
has a two-parameter solution
$$x=m^2+dn^2, \quad y=2mn, \quad z=m^2-dn^2. \qquad(\star)$$
He then says “there is no ready means for determining whether this is the general solution”, and goes on to give a [much more complicated] general solution.

Is Carmichael’s conclusion true? *i.e.* Can it neither be proven nor disproven [easily] that $(\star)$ is indeed a general parametric solution to $(\dagger)$?

EDIT: In Barbeau’s *Pell’s Equation* (pg. 36), it says:

> Exercise 2.8. [...] (a) Consider the case d=2 [of the equation $U^2-W^2=dV^2$]. Obtain the parametric solutions
>   $$(u,v,w)=(r^2+2s^2,2rs,2s^2-r^2)$$
>   and
>   $$(u,v,w)=(2r^2+s^2,2rs,s^2-2r^2).$$
>   (b) Obtain a parametric set of solutions for $u^2-dv^2=w^2$.

Given that this ‘exercise’ appears early in such an elementary textbook, it seems likely to me that there is a solution similar to $(\star)$ which *is* valid [though clearly $(\star)$ is not, as pointed out in the comments].

EDIT: Maybe Barbeau means let $d=d_1d_2$ and $v=v_1v_2$ be arbitrary factorizations, so that $dv^2=u^2-w^2=(u-w)(u+w)$ implies $u-w=d_1v_1^2$ and $u+w=d_2v_2^2$, yielding the parametric solution
$$(u,v,w) = \biggl(\frac{d_2v_2^2+d_1v_1^2}{2},v_1v_2,\frac{d_2v_2^2-d_1v_1^2}{2}\biggr).$$

Comment: Obviously $y$ from $(\star)\,$is always even, so the solution $x=2, y=1$ for $d=3, z=1$ cannot be produced.

Comment: Having just read the section, I'm not sure Carmichael is saying that it is unknown, but rather that the previous proof technique used before gives us no way to assert this. As previous commenter noted, this will only determine the points up to multiples.

Comment: This formula really makes all the decisions.  The formula has a General view there. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738446/solutions-to-ax2-by2-cz2/738527#738527  Interestingly, the formula for the equation $x^2+y^2=dz^2$ so simply cannot be recorded. It has a bulky look

Comment: Just for reference of others, here's a link to the book, which is public domain: http://www.gutenberg.org/files/20073/20073-pdf.pdf

Comment: Pythagorean triples and Hilbert’s Theorem 90
Noam D. Elkies  
I think this will be a nice short reference

Comment: So how does Elkies' paper jive with @gammatester's counterexample? His $A^2-4B$ would be $0^2-4(-3)=12$ which is not a square, so the parameterization should work, right?

Comment: Ah! If $(m,n)=1$, then you get
$$(x',y',z')=(m^2+3n^2,2mn,m^2-3n^2)=(4,2,-2)$$
which is, as claimed, proportional to the desired $(x,y,z)=(2,1,-1)$ [here with $z=-1$ instead of $+1$].

Any solution $(m,n)=(3n,n)$ will give you a solution proportional to $(2,1,1)$ [with $z$ positive. For example, $(m,n)=(3,1)$ yields
$$(x',y',z')=(m^2+3n^2,2mn,m^2-3n^2)=(12,6,6),$$
and dividing by $6$ gives you the desired $(x,y,z)=(2,1,1)$.

Yay, Noam!!  =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the ***complete*** rational solution to,

$$x^2+ny^2 = z^2$$

needs a ***third*** parameter, the scaling factor $t$, hence,

$$\big((a^2-nb^2)t\big)^2+n(abt)^2 = \big((a^2+nb^2)t\big)^2$$

**Proof of completeness:**

Let $xyz \ne 0$. Using a system of three equations,

$$\begin{aligned}
x\,&=(a^2-nb^2)t\\
y\,&=abt\\
z\,&=(a^2+nb^2)t
\end{aligned}$$

one can then ***rationally*** express the three unknowns $a,b,t$ in terms of the knowns $x,y,z$ by the simple formulas,

$$\begin{aligned}
a\,&=x+z\\
b\,&=y\\
c\,&=\tfrac{1}{2(x+z)}
\end{aligned}$$

though one needs a little algebraic manipulation to get these forms.

*P.S.* Just a minor quibble, $x^2-dy^2 =N$ is a *Pell-like equation*, while $ax^2+by^2+cz^2 = 0$ is a *ternary quadratic form*.

Comment: Yes, your scaling factor is Elkies’s "proportional to".