# Complicated unusual Pell equation

Tags: number-theory, pell-type-equations

I am trying to find the five smallest pairs of positive integers p,q that satisfy the unusual Pell equation 
$$p^2− \frac{251934169}{4} q^2 = 1.$$

One obvious trivial solution is p=1 and q=0 , but this does not count. I am trying to find the five smallest pairs of positive integers p,q that satisfy this equation. Note that the coefficient of $$q^2$$ is not an integer but is a rational number.  I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Why don't you write then a rational number? $p^2-\frac{251934169}{4}q^2=1$, or just $4p^2-251934169q^2=4$. Where did you get the number $251934169=17\cdot 73\cdot 89\cdot 2281$?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde . Yes you are right.  But I wrote the Pell equation in standard form.

Comment: Decimal expressions for rational numbers is not the standard form for Pell equations, I think. Instead of Pell you can consider [Legendre](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985733/can-legendres-theorem-really-help-solve-this-equation-ax2by2-cz2?rq=1).

Comment: The solutions to this unusual Pell Equation will help me compute a new Ramanujan-Hirschhorn Matirx  which generates an infinite number of Fermat-near-miss triples .

Comment: So [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3437329/how-can-i-compute-a-3-by-3-unimodular-matrix-which-produces-an-infinite-number-o) might help for understanding your motivation.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde . Yes the solutions to this Pell Equation will help me compute a new Ramanujan-Hirschhorn  Matrix.

Comment: My answer is below. That matrix is going to have large entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If
$p^2− \frac{251934169}{4} q^2 = 1
$,
then
$4p^2− 251934169q^2 = 4
$,
so that $q$ has to be even.

Let $q = 2y$
so that
$4p^2− 251934169\cdot 4 y^2 = 4
$
or
$p^2− 251934169 y^2 = 1
$
and this becomes
a standard Pell equation.

After searching
for a Pell equation solver
that could solve this,
I found
http://www.numbertheory.org/php/pell.php
which said that

the least solution of $u^2-251934169·v^2=1$
 is (u,v)=(225271244990700943315267956280411800555634015051308090277884868604104962338540162508662780103851110134288923470733214492576705304921942447496877316432148755394149624610709778342253829532034182955585281785605125774062067042871533474548723189550080879461940755054931210785029037747926428769992333668074349218880978527807663394127680486193384843986997533304388501754725074957250497216933172269065473852746178843181608306140365685996039286536330244666823292214037380277106713895640581283369187712083172695225344399463019401537455882605714942067846468852520297222251755337316170041845823661624202782666250115734237819683042082985171526282800382222714576727626094980629885366352000131303132135359463108635521565410488112287912844686192672738472001947756812093648970418119040213989933215258586913997217342108856777957037627456499897383934170286644285878283503578561992303795946148570976156177701503287373115452930781765236053893727748799204417831966968237024161827983124601075826155762117660452380906950456102876389134502447701968296040064628681054852876640098371536019198418255253941528944307814328148190184143000799951889089084659644347638577183884192073467082108506523506372732340274528141456740473415969963650656773018158163222322270988303396424521240862140458260591486474043045092368034899520901292279521856198411310822116084681636806884280270173841934612885750400068863907732865349185857915555235934810570449154233256465716941270067608222665579808387449666859364948244303214692248884665160509209379252943392494272634976297214741913847533965479527154125323880743892254267831724482576916275662958095933387932932551059660582766222292883165493697748307219389789209133143531345455092189866850439804333199651752360242139683699342368412986247802850384829304599110060419091883992716219173015297451039403047743238488985860729267543533352329687314970438461416693387772967943131761604987413334536162985092790422123282237028624645785633489664726218957148609919685769428122222084852809562569214413965720771408729185099918424343296677568166613090433613515483031252901694323178595995462642028964386862010093420726769418355184234720946181775332737659395967587225532076407623909565596790910765885818561865412162538848363553668612714198691288861437047601157353591221118724976585902490459382998907534939868158790879001671152433044317432949761648923963614896693699457510715718361695625294634696966284878410574160929772400728092044256419270960522476326245255572559146175279700400659950509793788476378848175390369825427301273114735692514379330175924474553668351745584388982458068437797359188706503857643164095213477929089334214332342050356909188421399238606889543471922745845239071010651328302511512759263707483733323614395083737283232899508265127479172494312201913477981379407799842709252906180434716507141311051322982240657546127971114278462713116439134410377103157523161671298844486230796509326848933853071382190119442436807702852665446333225245223437120117269735297360569365484765265678599514845945070544634609637487148190908846353641866101791106162516313305822511866796089071796216876389782118935966244678804350508265429071175447438279751936690584484769952697448915336468581146844571603113602643709943866971797062017021207642033921312513697587999212884164536775768402206018046772509817554058217211657510926455226154119243190033360301765607288639334708843614852895130144204537103834220400026878753494472540566640552609407477709815083333874222841700725622211428144359211679202120655592804708419101143418091589880834113404679889876903100324371120800767782414611156383670868080765233711399358523011346075275028463738338742036397612554950891163082740807747720798395812396497715250419270439996118401688429363409408587403868552632449,

14192608484101852311652173245015908656804599176789443002894924495999549636714310791643897994105341662923337788807362492209151601295913400774106514453526713684300113833584020254065789648114268592736284956478181887539578184404968727535130675240301330680424045087937507751354783751843882083549961006487041762539143092240182267625673545543455936367146411970290305782054776154497199209337203912681883938910324043935778509782484042962801145769894029337234699854480354143198040854080038324908157243595282073438163655575224248176278517428229817251480464816158421625916354924041235208915540115080577922127171351419601521489833636713770490678523243460973684413305651071322894619250800870367143777158331968412485425107035913822330947567736802295289309310119051345239539416991493942015919622751790785348919038379805859227911049324217398997513740560122179284504743633281021356441339976860299787471756578513146889121257883460749829291521787806407625153692719275725372954170370022396315140061544307643175653776535400455073782043194286683651362868872913084605139896620681911829754951648855405035242954097123540546545699114503980773519800040686939458468363079503478112881810641405492312867968273945731622796829877056323659996692366270430039570246302826360217970167904052112666239140660239846400409281440873845501116446348007978493038509853751195440746244570564678705662263875503717637378479288532317999237973107560945322110329507371890363756609225345275053348896623790574378451171965349295601942657954603086798163818585160123133049105832566315756886174131977304383495738867259989933572107914654007602572072669886503835449434697082833959512274441463637591580987951456241751839753688294600046750422849927840261048311740759015102448579153671310998368053088014413525190580443197365032823977294039021848988011145065910397014584936450149791059595948730498821311193267054622077669604956790772519227683823436511355690914063750200890967538599655958474116254219092343844084126763004405544159971866399839778417472371540744843901169054419472383039900816397260964805188541414616285494763474041141378518475042644111271715236082099399166939856152460149713823550540711450666953940767069945152766271334212385420086229265163361958210608874053137385703689903131579849687810390459434530819888897316926006951015316039571670007909492659476534147543282568764219964830440993197525690257373171516463315610841446990538425316425355251031712246044841634387772586408427005184450884952092284031967616619098317229037204142888806862991799280665577744394701502355439865753451015144520995850646040168483054240045219151600299985495053865199334557347514401508695659852900307881024093654437140394704913020334654207296557171006143445535613450778534351554384994362657965164040526157761954009421379897594732901983494994792808653901666978465058145147354647254159740325889135516891795932511454135345954246797045832787125979302458944880231797844254718580918828915871316273175022436224022647959141841073343734570471214713851782861120193652913798107781606774103634812965681121606226667532526322123126746467720543222481394331092466461362151862939111283968719755841042222483184032785703070867059218255951365944496598450548638969450932368393283610523294144075386919088667617918737462345261757489235868698957598377417131105200698535366855674649415279001796791530769452086033364850542624709325984274768735921564813978980455723994052138769997183002925322064719114992191840357539339755443706277234339761275474258068517184163636886137772133041843474458907703473580758200124705007910905441490819887820473878036142169329356939728136901858192287740818406164859433087836097641719006150802492533584026676040865371473046576830869200861399986483430883990828196264177112291206269520)

Comment: The link should be: http://www.numbertheory.org/php/pell.html