# Prove that there exists infinitely many pairs of relatively prime integers $(a,b)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that there exists infinitely many pairs of relatively prime integers $(a,b)$ such that both the quadratic equations $$x^2+ax+b=0$$
>   $$     
> x^2+2ax+b=0$$
>   has integer roots.

I tried the following:
$a^2-4b=n^2$ and $a^2-b=m^2$

Eliminating $b$ from both we get

$3a^2=(2m+n)(2m-n)$

from here we get that $3a^2$ should have two factors whose sum is divisible by $4$. From here we can get the $b$ but the problem is both numbers should be relatively prime.

Comment: Can you please give the source of the problem

Comment: @Shivam Patel   Indian National Mathematical Olympiad-1995

Comment: The title of the question is somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 2):

You want
$$  3a^2 - 4 m^2 = -n^2.  $$ Suppose you have a single such expression, $a=1,m=1,n=1,$ call it $(a,m) = (1,1).$ You get infinitely many such expressions, with the same fixed value of $m,$ by repeating the mapping
$$ (a,m) \mapsto (7a+8m, 6a+7m).  $$
So, we have $(a,m)$ pairs
$$ (1, 1)  $$
$$ (15, 13)  $$
$$ (209, 181)  $$
$$ (2911, 2521)  $$
$$ (40545, 35113)  $$

We also get separate recursions for the $(a,m)$ components,
$$ a_{j+2} = 14 a_{j+1} - a_j,  $$
$$ m_{j+2} = 14 m_{j+1} - m_j.  $$
This is just the Cayley-Hamilton theorem. Similarly, the mapping preserves GCD, because
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
7 & 8 \\
6 & 7
\end{array}
\right)
$$
is of integers and determinant $1,$ that is, its inverse is also of integer entries. Back to Cayley-Hamilton, what is the characteristic polynomial for this matrix?

Comment: I was able to sketch this thing .Thus I asked for the source . Its an high school level olmpiad ! So I am afraid Cayley Hamilton won't be expected to be used

Comment: @ShivamPatel, of course. But the mapping given is valid, easily confirmed by hand for a high schools student, and takes positive solution pairs to larger integer pairs, hence an infinite set. Other quadratic form methods I have would be less acceptable still.

Comment: @ShivamPatel, I found the problem with the complete school level answer, here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082645/characterize-the-solution-of-a-diophantine-equation-x2py2-z2  It is a little different as it includes things like $x^2 + 5 y^2 + z^2$ or $x^2 + 13 y^2 = z^2$ rather than $x^2 + 3 y^2 = 4 z^2.$

Comment: @WillJagy wouldn't have thought to use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem to prove this,although it seems obvious when you put it that way! Connections in mathematics show up in the most unexpected places.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, given integers $g,h,$ with $\gcd(g,h)=1.$ such that $g$ is not divisible by $3$ and one of $g,h$ is even and the other odd, we get a primitive solution with
$$ n = -g^2 - 6gh+3h^2,  $$
$$ a = g^2 - 2gh - 3h^2,      $$
$$ m = g^2 + 3 h^2.  $$

These may not be all solutions to $n^2 + 3 a^2 = 4 m^2,$ the method is tricky. You can take the absolute values of the numbers in any case. Solutions that may be different come from this sort of thing: take $g = 3 \gamma,$ now all $n,a,m$ are divisible by $3,$ just divide through by $3.$ The other variant is to take both $g,h$ odd, now all $n,a,m$ are even, just divide through by $2,$ or, if necessary, by $4.$

Sunday: maybe the best way to say it is this: the possible values are
$$  \gcd(n,a,m) \in \{ 1, 3, 4, 12. \}  $$
To get **all** triples, use the recipe above with $\gcd(g,h)=1$ but forget about my other restrictions, and divide through by the gcd. Oh, and use absolute value signs, although that will lead to a certain degree of repetition.

Below is what happens with actual numbers, lots of repetition:

```
    m              a            n                 g        h
     1 a:          0 n:          2 gcd 12 g:      3 h:      1
     1 a:          0 n:          2 gcd  4 g:      1 h:     -1
     1 a:          1 n:          1 gcd 12 g:      3 h:     -1
     1 a:          1 n:          1 gcd  1 g:      1 h:      0
     1 a:          1 n:          1 gcd  3 g:      0 h:      1
     1 a:          1 n:          1 gcd  3 g:      0 h:     -1
     1 a:          1 n:          1 gcd  4 g:      1 h:      1
     7 a:          3 n:         13 gcd 12 g:      3 h:     -5
     7 a:          3 n:         13 gcd  1 g:      2 h:      1
     7 a:          3 n:         13 gcd  3 g:      3 h:     -2
     7 a:          3 n:         13 gcd  4 g:      5 h:      1
     7 a:          5 n:         11 gcd 12 g:      9 h:      1
     7 a:          5 n:         11 gcd  1 g:      2 h:     -1
     7 a:          5 n:         11 gcd  3 g:      3 h:      2
     7 a:          5 n:         11 gcd  4 g:      1 h:     -3
     7 a:          8 n:          2 gcd 12 g:      3 h:      5
     7 a:          8 n:          2 gcd 12 g:      9 h:     -1
     7 a:          8 n:          2 gcd  4 g:      1 h:      3
     7 a:          8 n:          2 gcd  4 g:      5 h:     -1
    13 a:         15 n:          1 gcd 12 g:      3 h:      7
    13 a:         15 n:          1 gcd  1 g:      1 h:      2
    13 a:         15 n:          1 gcd  3 g:      6 h:     -1
    13 a:         15 n:          1 gcd  4 g:      7 h:     -1
    13 a:          7 n:         23 gcd 12 g:      9 h:      5
    13 a:          7 n:         23 gcd  1 g:      1 h:     -2
    13 a:          7 n:         23 gcd  3 g:      6 h:      1
    13 a:          7 n:         23 gcd  4 g:      5 h:     -3
    13 a:          8 n:         22 gcd 12 g:      3 h:     -7
    13 a:          8 n:         22 gcd 12 g:      9 h:     -5
    13 a:          8 n:         22 gcd  4 g:      5 h:      3
    13 a:          8 n:         22 gcd  4 g:      7 h:      1
    19 a:         16 n:         26 gcd 12 g:     15 h:      1
    19 a:         16 n:         26 gcd 12 g:      9 h:      7
    19 a:         16 n:         26 gcd  4 g:      1 h:     -5
    19 a:         16 n:         26 gcd  4 g:      7 h:     -3
    19 a:         21 n:         11 gcd 12 g:     15 h:     -1
    19 a:         21 n:         11 gcd  1 g:      4 h:     -1
    19 a:         21 n:         11 gcd  3 g:      3 h:      4
    19 a:         21 n:         11 gcd  4 g:      1 h:      5
    19 a:          5 n:         37 gcd 12 g:      9 h:     -7
    19 a:          5 n:         37 gcd  1 g:      4 h:      1
    19 a:          5 n:         37 gcd  3 g:      3 h:     -4
    19 a:          5 n:         37 gcd  4 g:      7 h:      3
    31 a:         11 n:         59 gcd 12 g:     15 h:      7
    31 a:         11 n:         59 gcd  1 g:      2 h:     -3
    31 a:         11 n:         59 gcd  3 g:      9 h:      2
    31 a:         11 n:         59 gcd  4 g:      7 h:     -5
    31 a:         24 n:         46 gcd 12 g:     15 h:     -7
    31 a:         24 n:         46 gcd 12 g:      3 h:    -11
    31 a:         24 n:         46 gcd  4 g:     11 h:      1
    31 a:         24 n:         46 gcd  4 g:      7 h:      5
    31 a:         35 n:         13 gcd 12 g:      3 h:     11
    31 a:         35 n:         13 gcd  1 g:      2 h:      3
    31 a:         35 n:         13 gcd  3 g:      9 h:     -2
    31 a:         35 n:         13 gcd  4 g:     11 h:     -1
    37 a:         33 n:         47 gcd 12 g:     21 h:      1
    37 a:         33 n:         47 gcd  1 g:      5 h:     -2
    37 a:         33 n:         47 gcd  3 g:      6 h:      5
    37 a:         33 n:         47 gcd  4 g:      1 h:     -7
    37 a:         40 n:         26 gcd 12 g:     21 h:     -1
    37 a:         40 n:         26 gcd 12 g:      9 h:     11
    37 a:         40 n:         26 gcd  4 g:     11 h:     -3
    37 a:         40 n:         26 gcd  4 g:      1 h:      7
    37 a:          7 n:         73 gcd 12 g:      9 h:    -11
    37 a:          7 n:         73 gcd  1 g:      5 h:      2
    37 a:          7 n:         73 gcd  3 g:      6 h:     -5
    37 a:          7 n:         73 gcd  4 g:     11 h:      3
    43 a:         13 n:         83 gcd 12 g:     21 h:      5
    43 a:         13 n:         83 gcd  1 g:      4 h:     -3
    43 a:         13 n:         83 gcd  3 g:      9 h:      4
    43 a:         13 n:         83 gcd  4 g:      5 h:     -7
    43 a:         35 n:         61 gcd 12 g:      3 h:    -13
    43 a:         35 n:         61 gcd  1 g:      4 h:      3
    43 a:         35 n:         61 gcd  3 g:      9 h:     -4
    43 a:         35 n:         61 gcd  4 g:     13 h:      1
    43 a:         48 n:         22 gcd 12 g:     21 h:     -5
    43 a:         48 n:         22 gcd 12 g:      3 h:     13
    43 a:         48 n:         22 gcd  4 g:     13 h:     -1
    43 a:         48 n:         22 gcd  4 g:      5 h:      7
    49 a:         16 n:         94 gcd 12 g:     15 h:    -11
    49 a:         16 n:         94 gcd 12 g:      9 h:    -13
    49 a:         16 n:         94 gcd  4 g:     11 h:      5
    49 a:         16 n:         94 gcd  4 g:     13 h:      3
    49 a:         39 n:         71 gcd 12 g:     15 h:     11
    49 a:         39 n:         71 gcd  1 g:      1 h:     -4
    49 a:         39 n:         71 gcd  3 g:     12 h:      1
    49 a:         39 n:         71 gcd  4 g:     11 h:     -5
    49 a:         55 n:         23 gcd 12 g:      9 h:     13
    49 a:         55 n:         23 gcd  1 g:      1 h:      4
    49 a:         55 n:         23 gcd  3 g:     12 h:     -1
    49 a:         55 n:         23 gcd  4 g:     13 h:     -3
    61 a:         56 n:         74 gcd 12 g:     15 h:     13
    61 a:         56 n:         74 gcd 12 g:     27 h:      1
    61 a:         56 n:         74 gcd  4 g:     13 h:     -5
    61 a:         56 n:         74 gcd  4 g:      1 h:     -9
    61 a:         65 n:         47 gcd 12 g:     27 h:     -1
    61 a:         65 n:         47 gcd  1 g:      7 h:     -2
    61 a:         65 n:         47 gcd  3 g:      6 h:      7
    61 a:         65 n:         47 gcd  4 g:      1 h:      9
    61 a:          9 n:        121 gcd 12 g:     15 h:    -13
    61 a:          9 n:        121 gcd  1 g:      7 h:      2
    61 a:          9 n:        121 gcd  3 g:      6 h:     -7
    61 a:          9 n:        121 gcd  4 g:     13 h:      5
    67 a:         32 n:        122 gcd 12 g:     21 h:     11
    67 a:         32 n:        122 gcd 12 g:     27 h:      5
    67 a:         32 n:        122 gcd  4 g:     11 h:     -7
    67 a:         32 n:        122 gcd  4 g:      5 h:     -9
    67 a:         45 n:        109 gcd 12 g:     21 h:    -11
    67 a:         45 n:        109 gcd  1 g:      8 h:      1
    67 a:         45 n:        109 gcd  3 g:      3 h:     -8
    67 a:         45 n:        109 gcd  4 g:     11 h:      7
    67 a:         77 n:         13 gcd 12 g:     27 h:     -5
    67 a:         77 n:         13 gcd  1 g:      8 h:     -1
    67 a:         77 n:         13 gcd  3 g:      3 h:      8
    67 a:         77 n:         13 gcd  4 g:      5 h:      9
    73 a:         17 n:        143 gcd 12 g:     27 h:      7
    73 a:         17 n:        143 gcd  1 g:      5 h:     -4
    73 a:         17 n:        143 gcd  3 g:     12 h:      5
    73 a:         17 n:        143 gcd  4 g:      7 h:     -9
    73 a:         63 n:         97 gcd 12 g:      3 h:    -17
    73 a:         63 n:         97 gcd  1 g:      5 h:      4
    73 a:         63 n:         97 gcd  3 g:     12 h:     -5
    73 a:         63 n:         97 gcd  4 g:     17 h:      1
    73 a:         80 n:         46 gcd 12 g:     27 h:     -7
    73 a:         80 n:         46 gcd 12 g:      3 h:     17
    73 a:         80 n:         46 gcd  4 g:     17 h:     -1
    73 a:         80 n:         46 gcd  4 g:      7 h:      9
    79 a:         40 n:        142 gcd 12 g:     21 h:    -13
    79 a:         40 n:        142 gcd 12 g:      9 h:    -17
    79 a:         40 n:        142 gcd  4 g:     13 h:      7
    79 a:         40 n:        142 gcd  4 g:     17 h:      3
    79 a:         51 n:        131 gcd 12 g:     21 h:     13
    79 a:         51 n:        131 gcd  1 g:      2 h:     -5
    79 a:         51 n:        131 gcd  3 g:     15 h:      2
    79 a:         51 n:        131 gcd  4 g:     13 h:     -7
    79 a:         91 n:         11 gcd 12 g:      9 h:     17
    79 a:         91 n:         11 gcd  1 g:      2 h:      5
    79 a:         91 n:         11 gcd  3 g:     15 h:     -2
    79 a:         91 n:         11 gcd  4 g:     17 h:     -3
    91 a:         11 n:        181 gcd 12 g:     15 h:    -17
    91 a:         11 n:        181 gcd  1 g:      8 h:      3
    91 a:         11 n:        181 gcd  3 g:      9 h:     -8
    91 a:         11 n:        181 gcd  4 g:     17 h:      5
    91 a:         19 n:        179 gcd 12 g:     27 h:     11
    91 a:         19 n:        179 gcd  1 g:      4 h:     -5
    91 a:         19 n:        179 gcd  3 g:     15 h:      4
    91 a:         19 n:        179 gcd  4 g:     11 h:     -9
    91 a:         80 n:        118 gcd 12 g:     27 h:    -11
    91 a:         80 n:        118 gcd 12 g:      3 h:    -19
    91 a:         80 n:        118 gcd  4 g:     11 h:      9
    91 a:         80 n:        118 gcd  4 g:     19 h:      1
    91 a:         85 n:        107 gcd 12 g:     33 h:      1
    91 a:         85 n:        107 gcd  1 g:      8 h:     -3
    91 a:         85 n:        107 gcd  3 g:      9 h:      8
    91 a:         85 n:        107 gcd  4 g:      1 h:    -11
    91 a:         96 n:         74 gcd 12 g:     15 h:     17
    91 a:         96 n:         74 gcd 12 g:     33 h:     -1
    91 a:         96 n:         74 gcd  4 g:     17 h:     -5
    91 a:         96 n:         74 gcd  4 g:      1 h:     11
    91 a:         99 n:         61 gcd 12 g:      3 h:     19
    91 a:         99 n:         61 gcd  1 g:      4 h:      5
    91 a:         99 n:         61 gcd  3 g:     15 h:     -4
    91 a:         99 n:         61 gcd  4 g:     19 h:     -1
    97 a:        112 n:          2 gcd 12 g:     33 h:     -5
    97 a:        112 n:          2 gcd 12 g:      9 h:     19
    97 a:        112 n:          2 gcd  4 g:     19 h:     -3
    97 a:        112 n:          2 gcd  4 g:      5 h:     11
    97 a:         55 n:        169 gcd 12 g:      9 h:    -19
    97 a:         55 n:        169 gcd  1 g:      7 h:      4
    97 a:         55 n:        169 gcd  3 g:     12 h:     -7
    97 a:         55 n:        169 gcd  4 g:     19 h:      3
    97 a:         57 n:        167 gcd 12 g:     33 h:      5
    97 a:         57 n:        167 gcd  1 g:      7 h:     -4
    97 a:         57 n:        167 gcd  3 g:     12 h:      7
    97 a:         57 n:        167 gcd  4 g:      5 h:    -11
   103 a:        117 n:         37 gcd 12 g:     33 h:     -7
   103 a:        117 n:         37 gcd  1 g:     10 h:     -1
   103 a:        117 n:         37 gcd  3 g:      3 h:     10
   103 a:        117 n:         37 gcd  4 g:      7 h:     11
   103 a:         40 n:        194 gcd 12 g:     27 h:     13
   103 a:         40 n:        194 gcd 12 g:     33 h:      7
   103 a:         40 n:        194 gcd  4 g:     13 h:     -9
   103 a:         40 n:        194 gcd  4 g:      7 h:    -11
   103 a:         77 n:        157 gcd 12 g:     27 h:    -13
   103 a:         77 n:        157 gcd  1 g:     10 h:      1
   103 a:         77 n:        157 gcd  3 g:      3 h:    -10
   103 a:         77 n:        157 gcd  4 g:     13 h:      9
   109 a:        119 n:         71 gcd 12 g:     15 h:     19
   109 a:        119 n:         71 gcd  1 g:      1 h:      6
   109 a:        119 n:         71 gcd  3 g:     18 h:     -1
   109 a:        119 n:         71 gcd  4 g:     19 h:     -5
   109 a:         24 n:        214 gcd 12 g:     15 h:    -19
   109 a:         24 n:        214 gcd 12 g:     21 h:    -17
   109 a:         24 n:        214 gcd  4 g:     17 h:      7
   109 a:         24 n:        214 gcd  4 g:     19 h:      5
   109 a:         95 n:        143 gcd 12 g:     21 h:     17
   109 a:         95 n:        143 gcd  1 g:      1 h:     -6
   109 a:         95 n:        143 gcd  3 g:     18 h:      1
   109 a:         95 n:        143 gcd  4 g:     17 h:     -7
   127 a:        120 n:        146 gcd 12 g:     21 h:     19
   127 a:        120 n:        146 gcd 12 g:     39 h:      1
   127 a:        120 n:        146 gcd  4 g:     19 h:     -7
   127 a:        120 n:        146 gcd  4 g:      1 h:    -13
   127 a:        133 n:        107 gcd 12 g:     39 h:     -1
   127 a:        133 n:        107 gcd  1 g:     10 h:     -3
   127 a:        133 n:        107 gcd  3 g:      9 h:     10
   127 a:        133 n:        107 gcd  4 g:      1 h:     13
   127 a:         13 n:        253 gcd 12 g:     21 h:    -19
   127 a:         13 n:        253 gcd  1 g:     10 h:      3
   127 a:         13 n:        253 gcd  3 g:      9 h:    -10
   127 a:         13 n:        253 gcd  4 g:     19 h:      7
   133 a:        120 n:        166 gcd 12 g:     33 h:    -13
   133 a:        120 n:        166 gcd 12 g:      3 h:    -23
   133 a:        120 n:        166 gcd  4 g:     13 h:     11
   133 a:        120 n:        166 gcd  4 g:     23 h:      1
   133 a:        143 n:         97 gcd 12 g:      3 h:     23
   133 a:        143 n:         97 gcd  1 g:      5 h:      6
   133 a:        143 n:         97 gcd  3 g:     18 h:     -5
   133 a:        143 n:         97 gcd  4 g:     23 h:     -1
   133 a:        153 n:         23 gcd 12 g:     39 h:     -5
   133 a:        153 n:         23 gcd  1 g:     11 h:     -2
   133 a:        153 n:         23 gcd  3 g:      6 h:     11
   133 a:        153 n:         23 gcd  4 g:      5 h:     13
   133 a:         23 n:        263 gcd 12 g:     33 h:     13
   133 a:         23 n:        263 gcd  1 g:      5 h:     -6
   133 a:         23 n:        263 gcd  3 g:     18 h:      5
   133 a:         23 n:        263 gcd  4 g:     13 h:    -11
   133 a:         65 n:        241 gcd 12 g:     27 h:    -17
   133 a:         65 n:        241 gcd  1 g:     11 h:      2
   133 a:         65 n:        241 gcd  3 g:      6 h:    -11
   133 a:         65 n:        241 gcd  4 g:     17 h:      9
   133 a:         88 n:        218 gcd 12 g:     27 h:     17
   133 a:         88 n:        218 gcd 12 g:     39 h:      5
   133 a:         88 n:        218 gcd  4 g:     17 h:     -9
   133 a:         88 n:        218 gcd  4 g:      5 h:    -13
   m              a            n                  g        h
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Worked out how to make two recipes and ignore gcd after calculations. The first recipe is in the earl;ier answer, take $\gcd(g,h) = 1,$ then $g,h$ not both odd, then $g$ not divisible by $3.$

The other recipe is $\gcd(u,v)=1,$ then $u+v$ not divisible by $3,$ recipes
$$ n = -u^2 -2uv +2v^2,   $$
$$ a = -u^2 +2uv ,   $$
$$ n = u^2 -uv +v^2.   $$

Put them together, we always get $\gcd(n,a,m) = 1,$ and up to $13 \cdot 19 = 247,$

```
    m             a            n       
     1 a:          0 n:          2 gcd  1 u:      0 v:      1
     1 a:          0 n:          2 gcd  1 u:      0 v:     -1
     1 a:          1 n:          1 gcd  1 g:      1 h:      0
     1 a:          1 n:          1 gcd  1 u:      1 v:      0
     1 a:          1 n:          1 gcd  1 u:      1 v:      1
     7 a:          3 n:         13 gcd  1 g:      2 h:      1
     7 a:          3 n:         13 gcd  1 u:      3 v:      1
     7 a:          3 n:         13 gcd  1 u:      3 v:      2
     7 a:          5 n:         11 gcd  1 g:      2 h:     -1
     7 a:          5 n:         11 gcd  1 u:      1 v:     -2
     7 a:          5 n:         11 gcd  1 u:      1 v:      3
     7 a:          8 n:          2 gcd  1 u:      2 v:     -1
     7 a:          8 n:          2 gcd  1 u:      2 v:      3
    13 a:         15 n:          1 gcd  1 g:      1 h:      2
    13 a:         15 n:          1 gcd  1 u:      3 v:     -1
    13 a:         15 n:          1 gcd  1 u:      3 v:      4
    13 a:          7 n:         23 gcd  1 g:      1 h:     -2
    13 a:          7 n:         23 gcd  1 u:      1 v:     -3
    13 a:          7 n:         23 gcd  1 u:      1 v:      4
    13 a:          8 n:         22 gcd  1 u:      4 v:      1
    13 a:          8 n:         22 gcd  1 u:      4 v:      3
    19 a:         16 n:         26 gcd  1 u:      2 v:     -3
    19 a:         16 n:         26 gcd  1 u:      2 v:      5
    19 a:         21 n:         11 gcd  1 g:      4 h:     -1
    19 a:         21 n:         11 gcd  1 u:      3 v:     -2
    19 a:         21 n:         11 gcd  1 u:      3 v:      5
    19 a:          5 n:         37 gcd  1 g:      4 h:      1
    19 a:          5 n:         37 gcd  1 u:      5 v:      2
    19 a:          5 n:         37 gcd  1 u:      5 v:      3
    31 a:         11 n:         59 gcd  1 g:      2 h:     -3
    31 a:         11 n:         59 gcd  1 u:      1 v:     -5
    31 a:         11 n:         59 gcd  1 u:      1 v:      6
    31 a:         24 n:         46 gcd  1 u:      6 v:      1
    31 a:         24 n:         46 gcd  1 u:      6 v:      5
    31 a:         35 n:         13 gcd  1 g:      2 h:      3
    31 a:         35 n:         13 gcd  1 u:      5 v:     -1
    31 a:         35 n:         13 gcd  1 u:      5 v:      6
    37 a:         33 n:         47 gcd  1 g:      5 h:     -2
    37 a:         33 n:         47 gcd  1 u:      3 v:     -4
    37 a:         33 n:         47 gcd  1 u:      3 v:      7
    37 a:         40 n:         26 gcd  1 u:      4 v:     -3
    37 a:         40 n:         26 gcd  1 u:      4 v:      7
    37 a:          7 n:         73 gcd  1 g:      5 h:      2
    37 a:          7 n:         73 gcd  1 u:      7 v:      3
    37 a:          7 n:         73 gcd  1 u:      7 v:      4
    43 a:         13 n:         83 gcd  1 g:      4 h:     -3
    43 a:         13 n:         83 gcd  1 u:      1 v:     -6
    43 a:         13 n:         83 gcd  1 u:      1 v:      7
    43 a:         35 n:         61 gcd  1 g:      4 h:      3
    43 a:         35 n:         61 gcd  1 u:      7 v:      1
    43 a:         35 n:         61 gcd  1 u:      7 v:      6
    43 a:         48 n:         22 gcd  1 u:      6 v:     -1
    43 a:         48 n:         22 gcd  1 u:      6 v:      7
    49 a:         16 n:         94 gcd  1 u:      8 v:      3
    49 a:         16 n:         94 gcd  1 u:      8 v:      5
    49 a:         39 n:         71 gcd  1 g:      1 h:     -4
    49 a:         39 n:         71 gcd  1 u:      3 v:     -5
    49 a:         39 n:         71 gcd  1 u:      3 v:      8
    49 a:         55 n:         23 gcd  1 g:      1 h:      4
    49 a:         55 n:         23 gcd  1 u:      5 v:     -3
    49 a:         55 n:         23 gcd  1 u:      5 v:      8
    61 a:         56 n:         74 gcd  1 u:      4 v:     -5
    61 a:         56 n:         74 gcd  1 u:      4 v:      9
    61 a:         65 n:         47 gcd  1 g:      7 h:     -2
    61 a:         65 n:         47 gcd  1 u:      5 v:     -4
    61 a:         65 n:         47 gcd  1 u:      5 v:      9
    61 a:          9 n:        121 gcd  1 g:      7 h:      2
    61 a:          9 n:        121 gcd  1 u:      9 v:      4
    61 a:          9 n:        121 gcd  1 u:      9 v:      5
    67 a:         32 n:        122 gcd  1 u:      2 v:     -7
    67 a:         32 n:        122 gcd  1 u:      2 v:      9
    67 a:         45 n:        109 gcd  1 g:      8 h:      1
    67 a:         45 n:        109 gcd  1 u:      9 v:      2
    67 a:         45 n:        109 gcd  1 u:      9 v:      7
    67 a:         77 n:         13 gcd  1 g:      8 h:     -1
    67 a:         77 n:         13 gcd  1 u:      7 v:     -2
    67 a:         77 n:         13 gcd  1 u:      7 v:      9
    73 a:         17 n:        143 gcd  1 g:      5 h:     -4
    73 a:         17 n:        143 gcd  1 u:      1 v:     -8
    73 a:         17 n:        143 gcd  1 u:      1 v:      9
    73 a:         63 n:         97 gcd  1 g:      5 h:      4
    73 a:         63 n:         97 gcd  1 u:      9 v:      1
    73 a:         63 n:         97 gcd  1 u:      9 v:      8
    73 a:         80 n:         46 gcd  1 u:      8 v:     -1
    73 a:         80 n:         46 gcd  1 u:      8 v:      9
    79 a:         40 n:        142 gcd  1 u:     10 v:      3
    79 a:         40 n:        142 gcd  1 u:     10 v:      7
    79 a:         51 n:        131 gcd  1 g:      2 h:     -5
    79 a:         51 n:        131 gcd  1 u:      3 v:     10
    79 a:         51 n:        131 gcd  1 u:      3 v:     -7
    79 a:         91 n:         11 gcd  1 g:      2 h:      5
    79 a:         91 n:         11 gcd  1 u:      7 v:     10
    79 a:         91 n:         11 gcd  1 u:      7 v:     -3
    91 a:         11 n:        181 gcd  1 g:      8 h:      3
    91 a:         11 n:        181 gcd  1 u:     11 v:      5
    91 a:         11 n:        181 gcd  1 u:     11 v:      6
    91 a:         19 n:        179 gcd  1 g:      4 h:     -5
    91 a:         19 n:        179 gcd  1 u:      1 v:     10
    91 a:         19 n:        179 gcd  1 u:      1 v:     -9
    91 a:         80 n:        118 gcd  1 u:     10 v:      1
    91 a:         80 n:        118 gcd  1 u:     10 v:      9
    91 a:         85 n:        107 gcd  1 g:      8 h:     -3
    91 a:         85 n:        107 gcd  1 u:      5 v:     11
    91 a:         85 n:        107 gcd  1 u:      5 v:     -6
    91 a:         96 n:         74 gcd  1 u:      6 v:     11
    91 a:         96 n:         74 gcd  1 u:      6 v:     -5
    91 a:         99 n:         61 gcd  1 g:      4 h:      5
    91 a:         99 n:         61 gcd  1 u:      9 v:     -1
    91 a:         99 n:         61 gcd  1 u:      9 v:     10
    97 a:        112 n:          2 gcd  1 u:      8 v:     11
    97 a:        112 n:          2 gcd  1 u:      8 v:     -3
    97 a:         55 n:        169 gcd  1 g:      7 h:      4
    97 a:         55 n:        169 gcd  1 u:     11 v:      3
    97 a:         55 n:        169 gcd  1 u:     11 v:      8
    97 a:         57 n:        167 gcd  1 g:      7 h:     -4
    97 a:         57 n:        167 gcd  1 u:      3 v:     11
    97 a:         57 n:        167 gcd  1 u:      3 v:     -8
   103 a:        117 n:         37 gcd  1 g:     10 h:     -1
   103 a:        117 n:         37 gcd  1 u:      9 v:     11
   103 a:        117 n:         37 gcd  1 u:      9 v:     -2
   103 a:         40 n:        194 gcd  1 u:      2 v:     11
   103 a:         40 n:        194 gcd  1 u:      2 v:     -9
   103 a:         77 n:        157 gcd  1 g:     10 h:      1
   103 a:         77 n:        157 gcd  1 u:     11 v:      2
   103 a:         77 n:        157 gcd  1 u:     11 v:      9
   109 a:        119 n:         71 gcd  1 g:      1 h:      6
   109 a:        119 n:         71 gcd  1 u:      7 v:     12
   109 a:        119 n:         71 gcd  1 u:      7 v:     -5
   109 a:         24 n:        214 gcd  1 u:     12 v:      5
   109 a:         24 n:        214 gcd  1 u:     12 v:      7
   109 a:         95 n:        143 gcd  1 g:      1 h:     -6
   109 a:         95 n:        143 gcd  1 u:      5 v:     12
   109 a:         95 n:        143 gcd  1 u:      5 v:     -7
   127 a:        120 n:        146 gcd  1 u:      6 v:     13
   127 a:        120 n:        146 gcd  1 u:      6 v:     -7
   127 a:        133 n:        107 gcd  1 g:     10 h:     -3
   127 a:        133 n:        107 gcd  1 u:      7 v:     13
   127 a:        133 n:        107 gcd  1 u:      7 v:     -6
   127 a:         13 n:        253 gcd  1 g:     10 h:      3
   127 a:         13 n:        253 gcd  1 u:     13 v:      6
   127 a:         13 n:        253 gcd  1 u:     13 v:      7
   133 a:        120 n:        166 gcd  1 u:     12 v:      1
   133 a:        120 n:        166 gcd  1 u:     12 v:     11
   133 a:        143 n:         97 gcd  1 g:      5 h:      6
   133 a:        143 n:         97 gcd  1 u:     11 v:     -1
   133 a:        143 n:         97 gcd  1 u:     11 v:     12
   133 a:        153 n:         23 gcd  1 g:     11 h:     -2
   133 a:        153 n:         23 gcd  1 u:      9 v:     13
   133 a:        153 n:         23 gcd  1 u:      9 v:     -4
   133 a:         23 n:        263 gcd  1 g:      5 h:     -6
   133 a:         23 n:        263 gcd  1 u:      1 v:    -11
   133 a:         23 n:        263 gcd  1 u:      1 v:     12
   133 a:         65 n:        241 gcd  1 g:     11 h:      2
   133 a:         65 n:        241 gcd  1 u:     13 v:      4
   133 a:         65 n:        241 gcd  1 u:     13 v:      9
   133 a:         88 n:        218 gcd  1 u:      4 v:     13
   133 a:         88 n:        218 gcd  1 u:      4 v:     -9
   139 a:        160 n:         22 gcd  1 u:     10 v:     13
   139 a:        160 n:         22 gcd  1 u:     10 v:     -3
   139 a:         69 n:        251 gcd  1 g:      8 h:     -5
   139 a:         69 n:        251 gcd  1 u:      3 v:    -10
   139 a:         69 n:        251 gcd  1 u:      3 v:     13
   139 a:         91 n:        229 gcd  1 g:      8 h:      5
   139 a:         91 n:        229 gcd  1 u:     13 v:     10
   139 a:         91 n:        229 gcd  1 u:     13 v:      3
   151 a:        115 n:        227 gcd  1 g:      2 h:     -7
   151 a:        115 n:        227 gcd  1 u:      5 v:     14
   151 a:        115 n:        227 gcd  1 u:      5 v:     -9
   151 a:        171 n:         59 gcd  1 g:      2 h:      7
   151 a:        171 n:         59 gcd  1 u:      9 v:     14
   151 a:        171 n:         59 gcd  1 u:      9 v:     -5
   151 a:         56 n:        286 gcd  1 u:     14 v:      5
   151 a:         56 n:        286 gcd  1 u:     14 v:      9
   157 a:        143 n:        193 gcd  1 g:      7 h:      6
   157 a:        143 n:        193 gcd  1 u:     13 v:      1
   157 a:        143 n:        193 gcd  1 u:     13 v:     12
   157 a:        168 n:        118 gcd  1 u:     12 v:     -1
   157 a:        168 n:        118 gcd  1 u:     12 v:     13
   157 a:         25 n:        311 gcd  1 g:      7 h:     -6
   157 a:         25 n:        311 gcd  1 u:      1 v:    -12
   157 a:         25 n:        311 gcd  1 u:      1 v:     13
   163 a:        112 n:        262 gcd  1 u:     14 v:     11
   163 a:        112 n:        262 gcd  1 u:     14 v:      3
   163 a:        187 n:         37 gcd  1 g:      4 h:      7
   163 a:        187 n:         37 gcd  1 u:     11 v:     14
   163 a:        187 n:         37 gcd  1 u:     11 v:     -3
   163 a:         75 n:        299 gcd  1 g:      4 h:     -7
   163 a:         75 n:        299 gcd  1 u:      3 v:    -11
   163 a:         75 n:        299 gcd  1 u:      3 v:     14
   169 a:         15 n:        337 gcd  1 g:     11 h:      4
   169 a:         15 n:        337 gcd  1 u:     15 v:      7
   169 a:         15 n:        337 gcd  1 u:     15 v:      8
   169 a:        161 n:        191 gcd  1 g:     11 h:     -4
   169 a:        161 n:        191 gcd  1 u:      7 v:     15
   169 a:        161 n:        191 gcd  1 u:      7 v:     -8
   169 a:        176 n:        146 gcd  1 u:      8 v:     15
   169 a:        176 n:        146 gcd  1 u:      8 v:     -7
   181 a:        104 n:        314 gcd  1 u:      4 v:    -11
   181 a:        104 n:        314 gcd  1 u:      4 v:     15
   181 a:        105 n:        313 gcd  1 g:     13 h:      2
   181 a:        105 n:        313 gcd  1 u:     15 v:     11
   181 a:        105 n:        313 gcd  1 u:     15 v:      4
   181 a:        209 n:          1 gcd  1 g:     13 h:     -2
   181 a:        209 n:          1 gcd  1 u:     11 v:     15
   181 a:        209 n:          1 gcd  1 u:     11 v:     -4
   193 a:        175 n:        239 gcd  1 g:      1 h:     -8
   193 a:        175 n:        239 gcd  1 u:      7 v:     16
   193 a:        175 n:        239 gcd  1 u:      7 v:     -9
   193 a:        207 n:        143 gcd  1 g:      1 h:      8
   193 a:        207 n:        143 gcd  1 u:      9 v:     16
   193 a:        207 n:        143 gcd  1 u:      9 v:     -7
   193 a:         32 n:        382 gcd  1 u:     16 v:      7
   193 a:         32 n:        382 gcd  1 u:     16 v:      9
   199 a:        165 n:        277 gcd  1 g:     14 h:      1
   199 a:        165 n:        277 gcd  1 u:     15 v:     13
   199 a:        165 n:        277 gcd  1 u:     15 v:      2
   199 a:        221 n:        109 gcd  1 g:     14 h:     -1
   199 a:        221 n:        109 gcd  1 u:     13 v:     15
   199 a:        221 n:        109 gcd  1 u:     13 v:     -2
   199 a:         56 n:        386 gcd  1 u:      2 v:    -13
   199 a:         56 n:        386 gcd  1 u:      2 v:     15
   211 a:        195 n:        253 gcd  1 g:      8 h:      7
   211 a:        195 n:        253 gcd  1 u:     15 v:      1
   211 a:        195 n:        253 gcd  1 u:     15 v:     14
   211 a:        224 n:        166 gcd  1 u:     14 v:     -1
   211 a:        224 n:        166 gcd  1 u:     14 v:     15
   211 a:         29 n:        419 gcd  1 g:      8 h:     -7
   211 a:         29 n:        419 gcd  1 u:      1 v:    -14
   211 a:         29 n:        419 gcd  1 u:      1 v:     15
   217 a:        160 n:        334 gcd  1 u:     16 v:     13
   217 a:        160 n:        334 gcd  1 u:     16 v:      3
   217 a:         17 n:        433 gcd  1 g:     13 h:      4
   217 a:         17 n:        433 gcd  1 u:     17 v:      8
   217 a:         17 n:        433 gcd  1 u:     17 v:      9
   217 a:        208 n:        242 gcd  1 u:      8 v:     17
   217 a:        208 n:        242 gcd  1 u:      8 v:     -9
   217 a:        225 n:        191 gcd  1 g:     13 h:     -4
   217 a:        225 n:        191 gcd  1 u:      9 v:     17
   217 a:        225 n:        191 gcd  1 u:      9 v:     -8
   217 a:        247 n:         73 gcd  1 g:      5 h:      8
   217 a:        247 n:         73 gcd  1 u:     13 v:     16
   217 a:        247 n:         73 gcd  1 u:     13 v:     -3
   217 a:         87 n:        407 gcd  1 g:      5 h:     -8
   217 a:         87 n:        407 gcd  1 u:      3 v:    -13
   217 a:         87 n:        407 gcd  1 u:      3 v:     16
   223 a:        168 n:        338 gcd  1 u:      6 v:    -11
   223 a:        168 n:        338 gcd  1 u:      6 v:     17
   223 a:        253 n:         83 gcd  1 g:     14 h:     -3
   223 a:        253 n:         83 gcd  1 u:     11 v:     17
   223 a:        253 n:         83 gcd  1 u:     11 v:     -6
   223 a:         85 n:        421 gcd  1 g:     14 h:      3
   223 a:         85 n:        421 gcd  1 u:     17 v:     11
   223 a:         85 n:        421 gcd  1 u:     17 v:      6
   229 a:        119 n:        409 gcd  1 g:     11 h:      6
   229 a:        119 n:        409 gcd  1 u:     17 v:     12
   229 a:        119 n:        409 gcd  1 u:     17 v:      5
   229 a:        145 n:        383 gcd  1 g:     11 h:     -6
   229 a:        145 n:        383 gcd  1 u:      5 v:    -12
   229 a:        145 n:        383 gcd  1 u:      5 v:     17
   229 a:        264 n:         26 gcd  1 u:     12 v:     17
   229 a:        264 n:         26 gcd  1 u:     12 v:     -5
   241 a:        224 n:        286 gcd  1 u:     16 v:      1
   241 a:        224 n:        286 gcd  1 u:     16 v:     15
   241 a:        255 n:        193 gcd  1 g:      7 h:      8
   241 a:        255 n:        193 gcd  1 u:     15 v:     -1
   241 a:        255 n:        193 gcd  1 u:     15 v:     16
   241 a:         31 n:        479 gcd  1 g:      7 h:     -8
   241 a:         31 n:        479 gcd  1 u:      1 v:    -15
   241 a:         31 n:        479 gcd  1 u:      1 v:     16
   247 a:        187 n:        373 gcd  1 g:     10 h:      7
   247 a:        187 n:        373 gcd  1 u:     17 v:     14
   247 a:        187 n:        373 gcd  1 u:     17 v:      3
   247 a:        203 n:        347 gcd  1 g:      2 h:     -9
   247 a:        203 n:        347 gcd  1 u:      7 v:    -11
   247 a:        203 n:        347 gcd  1 u:      7 v:     18
   247 a:        275 n:        131 gcd  1 g:      2 h:      9
   247 a:        275 n:        131 gcd  1 u:     11 v:     18
   247 a:        275 n:        131 gcd  1 u:     11 v:     -7
   247 a:        280 n:         94 gcd  1 u:     14 v:     17
   247 a:        280 n:         94 gcd  1 u:     14 v:     -3
   247 a:         72 n:        478 gcd  1 u:     18 v:     11
   247 a:         72 n:        478 gcd  1 u:     18 v:      7
   247 a:         93 n:        467 gcd  1 g:     10 h:     -7
   247 a:         93 n:        467 gcd  1 u:      3 v:    -14
   247 a:         93 n:        467 gcd  1 u:      3 v:     17
    m             a            n
```

---