# Parametrization to $4ax^2+4by^2=3t^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

fix $a$ and $b$ as rational numbers. If $x,y$ and $t$ be variable then how can I have a parametrization solution to this equation?

$$4ax^2+4by^2=3t^2$$

Comment: The formula in General there.    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738446/solutions-to-ax2-by2-cz2/738527#738527

Comment: there need not be any rational solutions whatsoever (other than $x=y=t=0$), for example $a=b=1$

Comment: If talking about the equation.  $$ax^2+by^2=3cz^2$$  decisions on these formulas can easily record selecting $c$ so that any of the $3c(a+b)$  ;  $a(3c-b)$  ;  $b(3c-a)$ was square.