# Quadratic Diophantine equations on the ring of polynomials

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations

The set of solutions of quadratic equation $a^2+b^2=c^2$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ can be described by Pythagorean triples up to multiplication. Can I use similar results on the ring of integer coefficient polynomials $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? More concretely,

(1) Is there a complete description of the set of solutions of $a^2+b^2=c^2$, $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

(2) In general, is there a theory on the class of equations $a^2+f(x)b^2=c^2$, where $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a given polynomial?

Comment: It's a triviality. Pythagorean triples. In General, the formula looks like this. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738446/solutions-to-ax2-by2-cz2/738527#738527  For the case of. $a^2+tb^2=c^2$ The solution is simple  $a=p^2-ts^2$ ; $b=2ps$ ; $c=p^2+ts^2$

Comment: Hmm, what if we consider Pell's equations? For example, if a=8, b=3, c=1, t=-7, then b cannot be even.

Comment: Everything can be. $p=3$ ; $s=1$ And to reduce common divisor 2.

Comment: Ah, thanks! It's interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pythagorean triples in  a polynomial ring $R[x]$ can be classified as follows (see Theorem $5.1$ in K. Conrad's notes [here](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEAQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uconn.edu%2F~kconrad%2Fblurbs%2Fugradnumthy%2Fpythagtriple.pdf&ei=4CpoVbD-HoSbsgHsoIDoCg&usg=AFQjCNFqTRJgbUS5usRNjkQRhsz_Hh4DWQ)):

*Theorem $5.1$*: All primitve Pythagorean triples $(f(t),g(t),h(t))$ with
$f^2+g^2=h^2$ are given by the formulas
\begin{align*}
f(t) & = c(k(t)^2-\ell(t)^2),\\
g(t) & = \pm 2c\cdot k(t)\ell(t),\\
h(t) & = \pm c(k(t)^2+\ell(t)^2),
\end{align*}
where $c\in R^{\times}$ and $k(t),\ell(t)$ are two relative prime polynomials in $R[t]$.

Comment: And what about the question 2?