# How to solve the equation $x^2+Dy^2=\alpha$ over finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

It is known that the equation $x^2+Dy^2=1$ is solved over finite fields $\mathbb{F}_q$ and we can point out the solutions . I wonder can we give solutions for the equation $x^2+Dy^2=\alpha$ for any $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{F}_q$?

Comment: You are interested in the solution of this equation in rational numbers?

Comment: You'd have to find one "obvious" solution to find all of them. If $\alpha$ is a perfect square, and you can find its square root, you are done, but that is not trivial.

Comment: ThomasAndrews: yes, because the solution of the first equation is the kernel of the norm map. But how can we point out a nontrivial solution for the second?

Comment: I guess I realized that You need.  You can use this formula.   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738446/solutions-to-ax2-by2-cz2/738527#738527