# What is meant when a universal quadratic form is ternary?

Tags: number-theory, terminology, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

I am reading about quadratic forms from class notes of a senior and I am not able to understand what this terminology means:

A quadratic form is universal over K if it represents all totally positive algebraic integers $\alpha \in {O_K}^{+}$.

But what is meant when a universal form is "ternary"?

Kindly tell.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer well , I had searched google before posting this question and I  searched again but I can't find the definition. If you were able to find the definition , can you just post here as comment or answer?

Comment: "ternary form" or "ternary quadratic form"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that this quadratic form has 3 variables.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738446/solutions-to-ax2-by2-cz2/738527#738527