# Solving quadratic Diophantine $a x^2 + b y^2 = c z^2$ given $a,b,c$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I do not have much background in Diophantine equations, but I'm curious about how to find families of solutions to them, particular to equations that are quadratic in the variables. I'm trying to understand whether there are limitations to a procedure I've seen in a few locations on MSE, in that it might not provide a complete set of solutions.

---

It seems like there is a nice procedure for constructing solutions to equations of the type $$a x^2 + b y^2 = c z^2$$ when a solution exists. The recipe appears to be to consider rewrite the equation in terms of rationals $r,s$ so that $$a r^2 + b s^2 = c.$$ Given a solution to the original equation, we get a solution $(r_0, s_0)$ to the second equation. Then one solves the pair of equations
$$a r^2 + b s^2 = c$$
$$s = s_0 + m(r-r_0)$$
in terms of the rational number $m$, giving $r$ and $s$ as a rational function of $m$.

For example, up to a change in notation, Will Jagy [answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/249778) the question of finding solutions to $x^2+y^2 = 5 z^2$ by noting that $x=1,y=2$ is a solution. Following the steps above, he found
$$r = \frac{2 m^2 - 2 m - 2}{m^2 + 1}$$ $$s =  \frac{- m^2 - 4 m + 1}{m^2 + 1}.$$ Writing $m=\frac{p}{q}$, this gives
$$r = \frac{2 p^2 - 2 pq - 2q^2}{p^2 + q^2}$$ $$s =  \frac{- p^2 - 4 pq + q^2}{p^2 + q^2}$$
from which one can deduce that the set
$$(x,y,z) = (2 p^2 - 2 pq - 2q^2, - p^2 - 4 pq + q^2, p^2 + q^2)$$ solves the original equation of $x^2 + y^2 = 5 z^2$ for every $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$.

However, I'm having a hard time convincing myself that these are indeed *all* the solutions.

---

My question in particular is on $x^2 + 68 y^2 = z^2$. A little playing around gets the solutions $(x,y,z) = (1,4,33)$.

When I follow the procedure, I get

$$r = \frac{68 m^2-544 m-1}{33(1+68 m^2)}$$
$$s = -\frac{2 \left(136 m^2+m-2\right)}{33 \left(68 m^2+1\right)}$$
which to me signals that
$$(x,y,z) = (-68 p^2 + 544 p q + q^2,2 (136 p^2 + pq - 2 q^2),  33 (68 p^2 + q^2))$$
solve the equation $x^2 + 68 y^2 = z^2$.

However, I again fear that this is not giving all solutions to the Diophantine equation. For example, I fear it's missing $(x,y,z) = (8,3,26)$.

---

Can I use the technique above or a modification of it to find the complete set of solutions to a given Diophantine equation $a x^2 + b y^2 = c z^2$ (specifically, one that has solutions and for which I know a particular solution)? For example, how should I modify or supplement the solution above for $x^2 + 68 y^2 = z^2$ to get a complete set of solutions?

Comment: On [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#:~:text=Rational%20points%20on%20a%20unit%20circle,-3%2C4%2C5&text=Euclid's%20formula%20for%20Pythagorean%20triples,t%20is%20a%20rational%20number.) there is something about pythagorean triples. I think that with a bit of work the proof can be adapted even to the case you are interested in

Comment: well, stereographic projection around a solution point does give all rational solutions, but it may take care to take that and reproduce all  (primitive) integer solutions. At a minimum, you need $z = u^2 + 68 v^2$  along with $z = 4 u^2 + 17v^2.$   The second one   gives the $33$  in your $(1,4,33)$  I think I would have mentioned Mordell's book   where he proves that all solutions come in a finite number of Pythagorean Triple type bujnches of formulas.

Comment: but (1, 3, 26)  is wrong

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks! That makes sense that it captures the rational solutions, and that I might be missing getting all the primitive integer solutions. That's good to know that there are just a finite number of these types of formulas. Thanks for pointing out the typo, $(1,3,26)$ should be $(8,3,26)$.

Comment: I added some relevant computer output to my answer.

Comment: Other book _H. Cohen, Number Theory. Vol. I. Tools and Diophantine Equations, 2007, p. 345_. In [pari/gp](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html) solution can be obtained by code `M=matdiagonal([1,68,-1]);Q=qfparam(M,qfsolve(M))`. And rational parameters is valid, i.e. `u=3`, `v=1/2` return `(8,3,26)`.

Comment: user, I put a proof of the material about $xz - y^2$ at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972120/ternary-quadratic-forms/1976199#1976199  with brief references

Comment: @DmitryEzhov  thank you, I had not realized pari did that. Your observation about rational parameter values can lead to more parametrizations that complete the picture using only integers, I wrote them as    the one I named A: $$   x = |4u^2 - 17 v^2| \; , \; \; y = |2uv| \; , \; \; z = 4 u^2 + 17 v^2  $$   and the one I named B:

$$   x = |4u^2 +4uv - 16 v^2| \; , \; \; y = |2uv + v^2| \; , \; \; z = 4 u^2 +4uv + 18 v^2  $$

Comment: You might want to have a look at  [this](http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/a0.5int2009/a0.5int2009.pdf) paper of Max Alexeyev. It is  freely accessible, very explicit, and corrects some wrong formulas  given elsewhere in the literature.

Answer (score 1):

See how well these three recipes do. If i have time I write a program that finds all solutions by brute force, call those "raw," then compare with the recipes. Easy to miss comparisons by hand. Since you have $x^2 + 68 y^2 = z^2$  we may freely use absolute value signs.

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

A:

$$   x = |4u^2 - 17 v^2| \; , \; \; y = |2uv| \; , \; \; z = 4 u^2 + 17 v^2  $$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

B:

$$   x = |4u^2 +4uv - 16 v^2| \; , \; \; y = |2uv + v^2| \; , \; \; z = 4 u^2 +4uv + 18 v^2  $$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

C:

$$   x = |u^2  - 68 v^2| \; , \; \; y = |2uv | \; , \; \; z =  u^2  + 68 v^2  $$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Comparison program:

```
   1       0       1     C         1       0
   1       0       1       RAW   
   1       4      33     A         2       1
   1       4      33     A         2      -1
   1       4      33       RAW   
   8       3      26     B         1       1
   8       3      26     B         2      -1
   8       3      26       RAW   
   8       5      42     B         2       1
   8       5      42     B         3      -1
   8       5      42       RAW   
  13      18     149     C         9       1
  13      18     149     C         9      -1
  13      18     149       RAW   
  13       2      21     A         1       1
  13       2      21     A         1      -1
  13       2      21       RAW   
  16     105     866     B        13      -5
  16     105     866     B         8       5
  16     105     866       RAW   
  16       1      18     B         0       1
  16       1      18     B         0      -1
  16       1      18     B         1      -1
  16       1      18       RAW   
  16      39     322     B         5       3
  16      39     322     B         8      -3
  16      39     322       RAW   
  19      14     117     C         7       1
  19      14     117     C         7      -1
  19      14     117       RAW   
  19       6      53     A         3       1
  19       6      53     A         3      -1
  19       6      53       RAW
```

This is a page from Mordell, *Diophantine Equations*.

[image]

Comment: Very nice! It looks like Mordell is useful, and I think I can get it at the library this coming week. Feel free to direct me to Mordell, but could you discuss a little more how you found those three equations? Was it trial and error? The middle equation especially is very neat to me.

Comment: @user196574   I have a program I wrote myself. All along I have had programs that take symmetric matrices $A,B$   of integers,  then output integer  matrices $P$  that solve $P^T A P = B$ The relationship is called congruence.  When $A$  is the Hessian matrix of an integer quadratic form, I solve  $P^T A P = k H,$   where $H$ is the Hessian of $xz - y^2$  and $\det kH$ is a (positive) square multiple of $\det A.$